# Преобразование текста в path

Tags: svg

У меня есть `SVG` файл с текстом

```html
<svg width="430" height="133" style="background: pink">
   <text x="20" y="100" font-size="100" fill="blue">ПРИВЕТ</text>
</svg>
```

Мне необходимо преобразовать текст в `path`, что бы каждая буква стала путём, как это можно сделать?

JavaScript, редактор, online сервис - подходит любое решение, так как операция разовая.

Comment: https://github.com/shrhdk/text-to-svg пробовали?

Comment: @MadFox а что тот комментарий стёрли, он полезен.

Comment: @MadFox отлично, это хороший вариант с библиотекой

Comment: я решил, что человек с 9к рейтинга должен знать про AI и XD))))

Comment: @MadFox нет, я этой утилитой не пользовался, кроме того вопрос не только для меня, он может быть полезен для многих.

Comment: @MadFox может быть ответом оформите всё то что сюда писали?

Comment: понятно, тогда если текст не меняется динамически, то конечно проще в AI. я за репутацией не гонюсь)) если помог - буду рад)

Comment: @MadFox ну тогда хоть комментарий верните

Comment: не умею) если кому-то пригодится - текст перегоняется в path одним  кликом по выбранному тексту в контекстном меню приложений Adobe Illustrator / Adobe XD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В редакторе Inkscape перевести текст в path можно и так:

- выделяем текст;
- выбираем пункт меню **Контур->Оконтурить объект**.

Результат можно увидеть прямо из программы во встроенном редакторе XML:

- выбираем пункт меню **Правка->Редактор XML...** В нём подсвечивается код XML выбранных объектов.

Answer (score 5):

Конверторы из файлов формата *.eot, *.ttf, *.woff в svg шрифт

[CodeAndMore @font-face made simple tool](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/indexnew.php)

[onlinefontconverter.com](http://onlinefontconverter.com/)

[freefontconverter.com](http://www.freefontconverter.com/)

Comment: Ну тут получается весь шрифт преобразует, а мне нужно конкретный текст.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Только весь файл шрифта, онлайн конвертации одиночных символов я не встречал.

Answer (score 4):

Решение через **Inkscape**

Сохраняем картинку с текстом в `file_text.svg`.

Из консоли Windows запускаем:

```
inkscape file_text.svg --export-text-to-path --export-plain-svg file_shapes.svg
```

Получаем `file_shapes.svg` с `paths`.

Конечно пути к Inscape и файлам в команде выше должны быть полными, в моём случае это:

```
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\logo.svg" --export-text-to-path --export-plain-svg "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\logoRez.svg"
```

Ответ сделан на основе [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7742345/6580397).

Исходный файл.

```html
<svg width="460" height="133" style="background: pink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="www://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <text font-family="Arial" x="20" y="100" font-size="100" fill="blue">HALLOW</text>
</svg>
```

Результирующий файл после чистки [утилитой](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor) и вручную.

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="133" width="460">
  <g id="text2" aria-label="HALLOW" style="fill:#00f;font-family:Arial;font-size:100">
    <path id="path12" d="M28.01 100V28.42h9.47V57.81H74.69V28.42h9.47V100H74.69V66.26H37.48V100Z" style="fill:#00f;font-family:Arial;font-size:100"/>
    <path id="path14" d="M92.12 100 119.61 28.42h10.21L159.11 100H148.32L139.97 78.32H110.04L102.18 100ZM112.77 70.61h24.27L129.57 50.78q-3.42-9.03-5.08-14.84-1.37 6.88-3.86 13.67z" style="fill:#00f;font-family:Arial;font-size:100"/>
    <path id="path16" d="M166.39 100V28.42h9.47v63.13h35.25V100Z" style="fill:#00f;font-family:Arial;font-size:100"/>
    <path id="path18" d="M222.05 100V28.42h9.47v63.13h35.25V100Z" style="fill:#00f;font-family:Arial;font-size:100"/>
    <path id="path20" d="m275.22 65.14q0-17.82 9.57-27.88 9.57-10.11 24.71-10.11 9.91 0 17.87 4.74 7.96 4.74 12.11 13.23 4.2 8.45 4.2 19.19 0 10.89-4.39 19.48-4.39 8.59-12.45 13.04-8.06 4.39-17.38 4.39-10.11 0-18.07-4.88-7.96-4.88-12.06-13.33-4.1-8.45-4.1-17.87zm9.77 0.15q0 12.94 6.93 20.41 6.98 7.42 17.48 7.42 10.69 0 17.58-7.52 6.93-7.52 6.93-21.34 0-8.74-2.98-15.23-2.93-6.54-8.64-10.11-5.66-3.61-12.74-3.61-10.06 0-17.33 6.93-7.23 6.88-7.23 23.05z" style="fill:#00f;font-family:Arial;font-size:100"/>
    <path id="path22" d="M368.34 100 349.35 28.42h9.72l10.89 46.92q1.76 7.37 3.03 14.65 2.73-11.47 3.22-13.23L389.82 28.42H401.25l10.25 36.23q3.86 13.48 5.57 25.34 1.37-6.79 3.56-15.58l11.23-46h9.52L421.76 100h-9.13L397.54 45.46q-1.9-6.84-2.25-8.4-1.12 4.93-2.1 8.4L378.01 100Z" style="fill:#00f;font-family:Arial;font-size:100"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: а результат здесь, в сниппете можно разместить? Очень интересно посмотреть.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT сделал, исходный файл и результирующий

Comment: хорошо бы ещё оптимизировать, c помощью SVG-editor, чтобы убрать кучу не нужной информации https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor