# Преобразование шрифта HTML в SVG кривые

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Подобные вопросы были заданы в этих топиках:

[Преобразование текста в path](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/806426/28748)

[Как нарисовать букву S?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1110672/28748)

Всё понятно из топика, как повторить технику создания контура буквы с помощью векторного редактора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1">
  <path d="M2 0h28a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v28a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z" fill="#333"/>
  <g transform="matrix(0.97490305,0,0,0.9227226,0.37033357,1.2847719)" >
   <path fill="#ffffff" d="m4 21.6c1.3-0.1 2.5-0.2 3.8-0.3 0.2 2.3 1.3 4.6 3.4 5.7 3 1.7 6.8 1.8 10 0.6 2.1-0.7 3.7-3 3.2-5.3C23.9 20.1 21.7 19 19.7 18.5 16.1 17.4 12.3 17 8.9 15.2 6.5 13.9 4.9 11.3 5.1 8.5 5.2 5.2 7.6 2.3 10.7 1.3 14.2 0 18.2 0.1 21.7 1.4 24.7 2.5 27 5.5 27.3 8.7 27.7 9.6 26.9 9.6 26.2 9.6 25.3 9.7 24.4 9.7 23.5 9.8 23.3 7.4 21.8 5.1 19.4 4.4 17.1 3.8 14.5 3.8 12.2 4.5 10.1 5.1 8.4 7.5 9.2 9.7 9.8 11.7 12 12.3 13.8 12.8c3.5 1.1 7.4 1.4 10.6 3.3 2.5 1.5 4.1 4.4 3.8 7.3-0.2 3.5-2.8 6.5-6.1 7.6C18.8 32.3 15 32.2 11.5 31.3 8.1 30.4 5.2 27.7 4.3 24.2 4.1 23.4 4 22.5 4 21.6Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Вопрос:**

А если под рукой нет векторного редактора,  есть ли другая возможность получить контуры букв с помощью кривых SVG?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Необходимость в получении контуров букв с помощью SVG кривых, возникает, как правило, при вёрстке логотипа с анимацией, украшения веб странички различными трансформациями текста.

Довольно просто получить  кривые с помощью приложения: [**Google font to SVG path**](https://danmarshall.github.io/google-font-to-svg-path/)

Выбираем шрифт, размер шрифта, пишем слово, ставим галочку, если нужны патчи для каждой буквы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляем анимацию:

```
.v {
stroke-dasharray: 0,751;
animation:dash 8s forwards linear;
stroke:white;
stroke-width:2;
}
@keyframes dash {
100% {stroke-dasharray:751,0;fill: #005C29;}
}
```

```css
.v {
stroke-dasharray: 0,425;
animation:dash 6s forwards ease-in;
stroke:white;
stroke-width:2;
}
@keyframes dash {
100% {stroke-dasharray:425,0;fill: #007434;}
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="180" viewBox="0 0 550 180" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#151515" />
<g id="svgGroup" transform="translate(35 25)" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="#000" > 
 
<path class="v" d="M 48.711 79.014 L 13.48 17.559 L 0 17.559 L 0 8.496 L 45.199 8.496 L 45.199 17.559 L 28.83 17.559 L 55.621 67.176 L 82.695 17.559 L 66.496 17.559 L 66.496 8.496 L 109.09 8.496 L 109.09 17.559 L 96.346 17.559 L 60.945 79.014 L 48.711 79.014 Z M 52.959 82.979 L 63.664 82.979 L 98.498 21.523 L 113.168 21.523 L 113.168 11.385 L 115.434 11.385 L 115.434 23.676 L 99.914 23.676 L 65.08 85.131 L 54.148 85.131 L 52.959 82.979 Z M 56.188 59.586 L 35.74 21.523 L 49.277 21.523 L 49.277 11.385 L 51.543 11.385 L 51.543 23.676 L 39.479 23.676 L 57.547 57.264 L 56.188 59.586 Z M 3.682 23.676 L 3.682 21.523 L 11.725 23.676 L 12.971 23.676 L 3.682 23.676 Z M 70.178 23.676 L 70.178 21.523 L 77.428 21.523 L 76.238 23.676 L 70.178 23.676 Z" id="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>

<path class="v" d="M 191.275 54.885 L 134.012 54.885 A 17.124 17.124 0 0 0 135.476 60.064 A 15.669 15.669 0 0 0 136.646 62.135 Q 138.77 65.307 142.055 67.487 A 24.743 24.743 0 0 0 147.91 70.318 A 28.875 28.875 0 0 0 149.503 70.801 A 32.969 32.969 0 0 0 158.197 71.934 Q 161.879 71.934 165.702 71.339 A 55.801 55.801 0 0 0 171.198 70.208 A 49.074 49.074 0 0 0 172.924 69.725 A 48.263 48.263 0 0 0 176.138 68.641 A 36.596 36.596 0 0 0 178.984 67.431 Q 180.855 66.535 182.11 65.598 A 10.097 10.097 0 0 0 183.062 64.797 L 185.215 64.797 L 190.539 70.574 A 37.038 37.038 0 0 1 181.326 76.29 A 46.043 46.043 0 0 1 176.351 78.136 A 57.715 57.715 0 0 1 164.937 80.38 A 72.089 72.089 0 0 1 157.914 80.713 A 61.051 61.051 0 0 1 150.125 80.24 Q 145.995 79.708 142.422 78.578 A 37.826 37.826 0 0 1 142.366 78.561 Q 135.598 76.408 130.981 72.613 A 25.725 25.725 0 0 1 125.045 65.738 A 24.33 24.33 0 0 1 123.986 63.721 Q 121.607 58.623 121.607 52.732 A 30.109 30.109 0 0 1 123.816 41.291 A 26.815 26.815 0 0 1 130.443 31.719 Q 134.861 27.584 141.432 25.12 A 37.317 37.317 0 0 1 149.004 23.198 Q 152.606 22.656 156.668 22.656 A 52.17 52.17 0 0 1 164.328 23.193 A 39.205 39.205 0 0 1 171.225 24.837 A 32.117 32.117 0 0 1 178.31 28.22 A 27.669 27.669 0 0 1 182.1 31.152 Q 186.574 35.287 188.925 41.263 A 33.26 33.26 0 0 1 190.887 48.948 A 43.723 43.723 0 0 1 191.275 54.885 Z M 139.449 58.85 L 195.127 58.85 A 22.478 22.478 0 0 0 195.242 57.791 A 27.994 27.994 0 0 0 195.297 57.009 A 34.667 34.667 0 0 0 195.346 55.714 A 42.201 42.201 0 0 0 195.354 54.885 A 42.263 42.263 0 0 0 194.621 46.924 A 38.565 38.565 0 0 0 194.362 45.681 A 35.783 35.783 0 0 0 191.934 38.476 A 32.879 32.879 0 0 0 191.474 37.524 Q 189.576 33.758 186.801 30.643 A 29.216 29.216 0 0 0 180.514 25.318 A 25.589 25.589 0 0 1 187.396 29.368 Q 190.539 31.945 192.805 35.627 Q 195.07 39.309 196.345 44.123 A 37.443 37.443 0 0 1 197.375 49.898 A 49.041 49.041 0 0 1 197.619 54.885 A 17.379 17.379 0 0 1 197.617 55.125 Q 197.612 55.495 197.592 55.985 A 47.385 47.385 0 0 1 197.591 56.018 Q 197.563 56.697 197.506 57.547 Q 197.449 58.396 197.364 59.274 Q 197.279 60.152 197.166 61.002 L 143.641 61.002 A 7.569 7.569 0 0 0 144.595 62.258 Q 145.639 63.39 147.368 64.554 A 25.132 25.132 0 0 0 147.605 64.712 Q 150.494 66.609 155.082 67.912 A 20.867 20.867 0 0 1 151.402 67.598 A 17.99 17.99 0 0 1 149.786 67.232 A 19.014 19.014 0 0 1 146.478 65.992 A 16.739 16.739 0 0 1 145.312 65.363 Q 143.301 64.174 141.8 62.503 A 13.261 13.261 0 0 1 139.449 58.85 Z M 189.576 76.238 L 191.105 77.881 A 49.072 49.072 0 0 1 177.234 84.44 A 46.385 46.385 0 0 1 175.728 84.848 A 68.368 68.368 0 0 1 159.922 86.879 A 75.964 75.964 0 0 1 158.82 86.887 Q 150.164 86.887 143.74 85.314 A 37.259 37.259 0 0 1 139.761 84.111 Q 133.529 81.824 129.894 78.152 A 18.075 18.075 0 0 1 128.461 76.521 A 40.584 40.584 0 0 0 137.175 81.191 A 49.204 49.204 0 0 0 141.233 82.582 A 50.408 50.408 0 0 0 149.304 84.229 Q 153.233 84.719 157.63 84.734 A 81.718 81.718 0 0 0 157.914 84.734 A 71.174 71.174 0 0 0 169.916 83.755 A 61.363 61.363 0 0 0 175.104 82.639 Q 183.119 80.543 189.576 76.238 Z M 134.352 47.805 L 178.191 47.805 A 24.371 24.371 0 0 0 176.623 43.146 A 20.835 20.835 0 0 0 175.388 40.838 Q 173.49 37.779 170.715 35.712 A 20.491 20.491 0 0 0 165.305 32.85 A 23.589 23.589 0 0 0 164.371 32.54 A 24.706 24.706 0 0 0 159.269 31.554 A 30.268 30.268 0 0 0 156.555 31.436 A 29.944 29.944 0 0 0 151.685 31.816 A 23.991 23.991 0 0 0 148.2 32.653 A 22.82 22.82 0 0 0 143.671 34.659 A 19.735 19.735 0 0 0 141.602 36.052 Q 138.77 38.232 136.929 41.234 A 20.318 20.318 0 0 0 134.352 47.805 Z M 142.111 45.369 L 139.506 45.369 Q 141.602 40.725 146.104 38.063 A 19.084 19.084 0 0 1 153.497 35.588 A 24.239 24.239 0 0 1 156.555 35.4 A 27.725 27.725 0 0 1 161.284 35.797 A 20.295 20.295 0 0 1 164.406 36.586 A 17.721 17.721 0 0 1 165.532 37.015 A 15.034 15.034 0 0 1 167.838 38.218 A 12.739 12.739 0 0 1 168.959 39.025 A 9.609 9.609 0 0 1 170.754 40.911 A 8.686 8.686 0 0 1 171.281 41.744 Q 168.053 39.592 164.371 38.572 A 28.368 28.368 0 0 0 158.658 37.625 A 33.613 33.613 0 0 0 156.441 37.553 A 20.175 20.175 0 0 0 151.811 38.062 A 16.07 16.07 0 0 0 147.775 39.592 A 13.487 13.487 0 0 0 142.111 45.369 Z" id="1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>

<path class="v" d="M 211.779 79.014 L 211.779 70.518 L 224.24 70.518 L 224.24 33.984 L 211.779 33.984 L 211.779 24.355 L 236.418 24.355 L 236.418 33.814 Q 238.174 31.549 240.638 29.51 Q 243.102 27.471 246.217 25.941 Q 249.332 24.412 253.014 23.534 A 32.543 32.543 0 0 1 258.759 22.715 A 38.216 38.216 0 0 1 260.887 22.656 A 43.81 43.81 0 0 1 261.549 22.662 Q 262.566 22.677 263.912 22.737 A 122.373 122.373 0 0 1 264.002 22.741 A 30.937 30.937 0 0 1 266.71 22.98 A 27.358 27.358 0 0 1 267.57 23.109 L 267.57 34.211 A 28.953 28.953 0 0 0 263.662 33.588 A 43.064 43.064 0 0 0 260.379 33.421 A 39.127 39.127 0 0 0 259.924 33.418 A 25.379 25.379 0 0 0 251.469 34.818 A 24.275 24.275 0 0 0 251.343 34.862 A 22.436 22.436 0 0 0 244.121 39.054 A 22.044 22.044 0 0 0 239.169 45.275 A 25.117 25.117 0 0 0 238.91 45.766 A 22.724 22.724 0 0 0 236.886 51.605 A 28.459 28.459 0 0 0 236.418 54.828 L 236.418 70.518 L 256.809 70.518 L 256.809 79.014 L 211.779 79.014 Z M 240.383 67.119 L 240.383 59.926 A 35.704 35.704 0 0 1 240.717 54.922 A 26.774 26.774 0 0 1 241.742 50.41 Q 243.102 46.219 245.622 43.33 A 16.6 16.6 0 0 1 251.768 38.912 Q 255.393 37.383 259.924 37.383 Q 260.887 37.383 262.359 37.524 A 38.423 38.423 0 0 1 264.549 37.801 A 44.775 44.775 0 0 1 265.446 37.949 Q 267.061 38.232 268.703 38.657 A 22.541 22.541 0 0 1 270.352 39.149 A 17.257 17.257 0 0 1 271.648 39.648 L 271.648 26.281 L 273.914 26.281 L 273.914 42.48 A 28.769 28.769 0 0 0 271.613 41.613 A 33.734 33.734 0 0 0 270.487 41.263 A 49.148 49.148 0 0 0 266.749 40.328 A 41.018 41.018 0 0 0 263.982 39.845 A 35.695 35.695 0 0 0 263.096 39.733 A 33.782 33.782 0 0 0 261.474 39.588 Q 260.705 39.538 260.015 39.535 A 20.453 20.453 0 0 0 259.924 39.535 Q 255.789 39.535 252.589 40.895 A 14.608 14.608 0 0 0 247.18 44.803 A 16.256 16.256 0 0 0 244.638 48.843 A 20.347 20.347 0 0 0 243.81 51.033 A 24.485 24.485 0 0 0 242.871 55.48 A 32.499 32.499 0 0 0 242.648 59.359 L 242.648 67.119 L 240.383 67.119 Z M 215.178 82.979 L 260.887 82.979 L 260.887 73.689 L 263.152 73.689 L 263.152 85.131 L 215.178 85.131 L 215.178 82.979 Z M 215.178 40.102 L 215.178 37.949 L 221.861 37.949 L 221.861 40.102 L 215.178 40.102 Z" id="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>

<path class="v" d="M 287.508 79.014 L 287.508 70.518 L 297.137 70.518 L 297.137 9.063 L 284.676 9.063 L 284.676 0 L 309.314 0 L 309.314 32.908 A 29.01 29.01 0 0 1 317.916 26.862 A 33.851 33.851 0 0 1 319.368 26.225 A 32.809 32.809 0 0 1 330.076 23.85 A 38.503 38.503 0 0 1 332.254 23.789 A 46.344 46.344 0 0 1 339.337 24.306 A 34.403 34.403 0 0 1 346.386 26.14 A 35.299 35.299 0 0 1 352.611 29.218 A 28.7 28.7 0 0 1 356.751 32.37 A 26.329 26.329 0 0 1 362.996 40.885 A 25.572 25.572 0 0 1 363.151 41.234 A 25.464 25.464 0 0 1 365.332 51.543 A 31.581 31.581 0 0 1 364.442 59.16 A 27.272 27.272 0 0 1 363.038 63.353 A 26.036 26.036 0 0 1 356.468 72.557 A 29.279 29.279 0 0 1 349.066 77.378 A 35.244 35.244 0 0 1 346.159 78.561 Q 340.127 80.713 332.65 80.713 A 41.438 41.438 0 0 1 324.528 79.944 A 34.784 34.784 0 0 1 319.453 78.532 A 27.565 27.565 0 0 1 312.081 74.557 A 25.153 25.153 0 0 1 309.314 72.104 L 309.314 79.014 L 287.508 79.014 Z M 290.906 82.979 L 313.393 82.979 L 313.393 80.033 A 32.692 32.692 0 0 0 316.642 81.52 A 37.572 37.572 0 0 0 317.811 81.959 A 45.883 45.883 0 0 0 322.71 83.403 A 51.971 51.971 0 0 0 327.779 84.338 A 38.707 38.707 0 0 0 331.177 84.645 A 33.239 33.239 0 0 0 332.65 84.678 A 49.227 49.227 0 0 0 342.09 83.804 A 41.539 41.539 0 0 0 347.377 82.412 A 35.897 35.897 0 0 0 355.431 78.585 A 31.614 31.614 0 0 0 359.017 75.898 A 29.481 29.481 0 0 0 366.663 65.505 A 31.335 31.335 0 0 0 369.086 56.719 A 40.021 40.021 0 0 0 369.41 51.543 Q 369.41 47.635 368.532 44.293 Q 367.654 40.951 366.21 38.147 A 28.853 28.853 0 0 0 363.582 33.947 A 26.126 26.126 0 0 0 362.896 33.078 A 41.378 41.378 0 0 0 360.029 29.935 A 36.245 36.245 0 0 0 359.045 29 Q 362.104 30.586 364.454 33.021 A 24.774 24.774 0 0 1 368.419 38.431 Q 370.033 41.404 370.883 44.774 Q 371.732 48.145 371.732 51.543 A 39.946 39.946 0 0 1 370.836 60.162 A 33.02 33.02 0 0 1 368.9 66.185 Q 366.068 72.727 360.942 77.314 A 34.106 34.106 0 0 1 351.759 83.141 A 40.997 40.997 0 0 1 348.595 84.366 A 45.851 45.851 0 0 1 338.447 86.539 A 57.25 57.25 0 0 1 332.594 86.83 A 33.706 33.706 0 0 1 330.32 86.749 A 43.396 43.396 0 0 1 328.402 86.575 A 44.703 44.703 0 0 1 323.814 85.811 A 47.673 47.673 0 0 1 319.312 84.593 A 28.977 28.977 0 0 1 316.993 83.734 A 23.173 23.173 0 0 1 315.375 82.979 L 315.375 85.131 L 290.906 85.131 L 290.906 82.979 Z M 309.314 52.676 A 22.191 22.191 0 0 0 309.677 56.795 Q 310.175 59.428 311.354 61.54 Q 313.393 65.193 316.706 67.516 A 22.336 22.336 0 0 0 322.963 70.547 A 25.901 25.901 0 0 0 324.268 70.914 A 35.152 35.152 0 0 0 332.934 71.99 Q 337.521 71.99 341.231 70.574 A 18.512 18.512 0 0 0 346.191 67.781 A 17.094 17.094 0 0 0 347.575 66.553 A 17.355 17.355 0 0 0 351.349 60.923 A 20.17 20.17 0 0 0 351.625 60.237 Q 353.041 56.527 353.041 51.996 A 19.332 19.332 0 0 0 352.287 46.531 A 17.382 17.382 0 0 0 351.37 44.095 A 18.471 18.471 0 0 0 346.811 37.949 A 20.433 20.433 0 0 0 341.19 34.455 A 23.846 23.846 0 0 0 339.985 33.984 A 24.339 24.339 0 0 0 332.919 32.603 A 28.146 28.146 0 0 0 331.518 32.568 Q 326.816 32.568 322.767 33.984 Q 318.717 35.4 315.743 38.034 A 19.189 19.189 0 0 0 311.042 44.378 A 18.57 18.57 0 0 0 309.422 50.437 A 22.751 22.751 0 0 0 309.314 52.676 Z M 314.36 47.099 A 15.958 15.958 0 0 0 313.393 52.676 A 14.719 14.719 0 0 0 314.327 57.887 A 14.865 14.865 0 0 0 316.989 62.39 A 13.743 13.743 0 0 0 317.606 63.061 A 14.729 14.729 0 0 0 321.209 65.731 A 14.733 14.733 0 0 0 323.166 66.598 A 17.152 17.152 0 0 0 326.816 67.459 A 32.024 32.024 0 0 1 324.499 66.267 Q 320.433 63.952 318.377 61.002 A 14.23 14.23 0 0 1 315.771 52.676 A 15.504 15.504 0 0 1 315.772 52.631 A 13.619 13.619 0 0 1 316.848 47.267 Q 317.924 44.746 319.963 42.82 A 13.467 13.467 0 0 1 321.653 41.466 A 15.682 15.682 0 0 1 324.919 39.79 Q 327.836 38.686 331.518 38.686 A 34.482 34.482 0 0 1 333.824 38.761 A 28.53 28.53 0 0 1 338.371 39.422 Q 341.543 40.158 345.281 41.971 A 11.846 11.846 0 0 0 343.878 40.398 A 12.263 12.263 0 0 0 339.561 37.808 A 20.986 20.986 0 0 0 335.891 36.872 A 27.022 27.022 0 0 0 331.518 36.533 A 25.187 25.187 0 0 0 328.433 36.716 A 19.541 19.541 0 0 0 323.984 37.779 A 19.592 19.592 0 0 0 322.375 38.461 A 16.287 16.287 0 0 0 318.292 41.206 Q 315.941 43.387 314.667 46.332 A 15.199 15.199 0 0 0 314.36 47.099 Z M 313.449 24.639 L 313.449 2.889 L 315.715 2.889 L 315.715 23.506 L 313.449 24.639 Z M 288.074 15.18 L 288.074 13.027 L 294.758 13.027 L 294.758 15.18 L 288.074 15.18 Z" id="3" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>

<path class="v" d="M 441.004 30.416 L 441.004 24.355 L 465.359 24.355 L 465.359 33.984 L 452.898 33.984 L 452.898 70.518 L 465.359 70.518 L 465.359 79.014 L 441.004 79.014 L 441.004 71.65 A 26.405 26.405 0 0 1 435.991 75.559 Q 433.188 77.258 430.044 78.391 A 39.342 39.342 0 0 1 423.53 80.118 A 38.556 38.556 0 0 1 416.818 80.713 A 48.573 48.573 0 0 1 409.721 80.219 Q 405.847 79.647 402.54 78.41 A 30.319 30.319 0 0 1 402.488 78.391 A 33.568 33.568 0 0 1 396.504 75.468 A 26.961 26.961 0 0 1 392.18 72.132 A 25.731 25.731 0 0 1 385.949 62.956 A 29.537 29.537 0 0 1 383.854 51.883 A 26.317 26.317 0 0 1 385.637 42.463 A 30.506 30.506 0 0 1 386.062 41.404 A 28.046 28.046 0 0 1 392.203 32.423 A 32.122 32.122 0 0 1 392.604 32.03 A 31.175 31.175 0 0 1 399.182 27.237 A 39.077 39.077 0 0 1 403.338 25.262 A 34.509 34.509 0 0 1 411.382 23.12 A 46.168 46.168 0 0 1 418.064 22.656 A 40.707 40.707 0 0 1 421.536 22.811 A 50.078 50.078 0 0 1 423.757 23.053 A 38.612 38.612 0 0 1 429.817 24.355 A 33.858 33.858 0 0 1 435.736 26.763 A 24.986 24.986 0 0 1 441.004 30.416 Z M 396.145 51.43 A 22.814 22.814 0 0 0 396.673 56.432 A 18.922 18.922 0 0 0 397.815 59.926 A 19.259 19.259 0 0 0 401.931 65.96 A 18.549 18.549 0 0 0 402.375 66.383 A 20.221 20.221 0 0 0 408.254 70.131 A 23.408 23.408 0 0 0 409.229 70.518 A 23.876 23.876 0 0 0 416.363 71.954 A 27.716 27.716 0 0 0 417.781 71.99 A 28.095 28.095 0 0 0 423.19 71.452 A 26.324 26.324 0 0 0 428.515 69.81 A 24.932 24.932 0 0 0 433.386 67.034 Q 435.68 65.363 437.351 63.069 Q 439.021 60.775 440.013 57.83 A 18.809 18.809 0 0 0 440.865 53.883 A 23.927 23.927 0 0 0 441.004 51.26 Q 441.004 47.238 439.135 43.642 A 21.245 21.245 0 0 0 434.122 37.326 A 23.802 23.802 0 0 0 427.819 33.436 A 27.426 27.426 0 0 0 426.787 33.021 A 24.757 24.757 0 0 0 417.951 31.436 A 26.828 26.828 0 0 0 411.873 32.105 A 23.622 23.622 0 0 0 409.313 32.852 A 21.281 21.281 0 0 0 404.142 35.493 A 19.208 19.208 0 0 0 402.403 36.873 Q 399.486 39.479 397.815 43.188 A 19.068 19.068 0 0 0 396.236 49.351 A 23.12 23.12 0 0 0 396.145 51.43 Z M 400.619 47.31 A 16.65 16.65 0 0 0 400.053 51.713 A 21.011 21.011 0 0 0 400.056 52.087 A 18.673 18.673 0 0 0 400.902 57.405 Q 401.752 60.096 403.479 62.248 A 13.936 13.936 0 0 0 404.774 63.651 A 15.879 15.879 0 0 0 407.841 65.901 A 16.71 16.71 0 0 0 410.708 67.183 A 21.925 21.925 0 0 0 414.043 68.025 A 27.211 27.211 0 0 1 411.275 66.764 A 20.116 20.116 0 0 1 408.634 65.108 A 18.342 18.342 0 0 1 407.196 63.919 A 14.84 14.84 0 0 1 405.009 61.427 Q 403.621 59.416 402.998 57.037 A 18.195 18.195 0 0 1 402.669 55.517 A 21.041 21.041 0 0 1 402.375 51.939 Q 402.375 49.051 403.479 46.445 A 13.91 13.91 0 0 1 406.623 41.857 A 14.053 14.053 0 0 1 407.906 40.753 A 15.644 15.644 0 0 1 411.522 38.714 A 15.181 15.181 0 0 1 414.36 37.88 A 18.91 18.91 0 0 1 417.951 37.553 A 36.777 36.777 0 0 1 418.82 37.563 Q 420.675 37.607 422.31 37.84 A 20.613 20.613 0 0 1 425.598 38.572 Q 428.826 39.592 431.885 41.291 Q 431.57 40.779 430.926 40.144 A 14.31 14.31 0 0 0 430.299 39.563 A 10.648 10.648 0 0 0 429.958 39.278 Q 429.428 38.852 428.781 38.436 A 19.488 19.488 0 0 0 427.41 37.638 A 14.73 14.73 0 0 0 427.293 37.576 Q 426.408 37.115 425.369 36.725 A 23.9 23.9 0 0 0 423.275 36.052 Q 420.896 35.4 417.951 35.4 A 23.658 23.658 0 0 0 416.007 35.479 A 19.683 19.683 0 0 0 410.758 36.618 A 19.498 19.498 0 0 0 409.753 37.022 A 16.686 16.686 0 0 0 405.094 40.017 A 15.514 15.514 0 0 0 401.384 45.171 A 14.713 14.713 0 0 0 400.619 47.31 Z M 456.977 67.119 L 456.977 37.949 L 469.438 37.949 L 469.438 28.66 L 471.703 28.66 L 471.703 40.102 L 459.242 40.102 L 459.242 67.119 L 456.977 67.119 Z M 438.342 78.787 L 438.342 81.393 A 34.002 34.002 0 0 1 432.532 84.14 A 42.963 42.963 0 0 1 428.515 85.386 A 46.032 46.032 0 0 1 416.932 86.83 Q 412.797 86.83 408.832 86.179 A 39.32 39.32 0 0 1 403.648 84.975 A 33.998 33.998 0 0 1 401.469 84.225 A 27.758 27.758 0 0 1 397.189 82.166 A 23.931 23.931 0 0 1 395.408 80.996 A 17.267 17.267 0 0 1 392.501 78.368 A 14.825 14.825 0 0 1 391.16 76.578 A 29.098 29.098 0 0 0 394.907 79.125 A 34.163 34.163 0 0 0 396.428 79.948 A 40.288 40.288 0 0 0 402.299 82.364 A 44.235 44.235 0 0 0 402.715 82.497 Q 406.057 83.545 409.653 84.111 A 46.353 46.353 0 0 0 416.875 84.678 A 44.884 44.884 0 0 0 425.042 83.958 A 38.809 38.809 0 0 0 428.628 83.12 Q 434.094 81.563 438.342 78.787 Z M 444.402 82.979 L 469.438 82.979 L 469.438 73.689 L 471.703 73.689 L 471.703 85.131 L 444.402 85.131 L 444.402 82.979 Z" id="4" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: а можно как нибудь из картинки получить буквы svg?а то хотел использовать шрифт `ulm grotesk Bold` но он платный и бесплатная версия скаченная в inkscape не видит

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin  можно, но трудоёмко. Нужно загрузить картинку в векторный редактор и инструментом "Рисовать кривые Безье" нанести точки по контуру букв в картинке. Полученный path будет представлять контур буквы SVG, который можно будет анимировать, стилизовать. Задайте отдельный вопрос, но с конкретными примерами, чтобы можно было конкретно ответить.

Answer (score 5):

Пример анимации со шрифтом **Akronim**

*Вынужден дать второй ответ из-за ограничения 30.000 символов в сниппете*

```css
.v {
stroke-dasharray: 0,380;
animation:dash 6s forwards -0.25s ease-in, fill-path 2s forwards 6s ;
stroke:#FFF7C7;
stroke-width:2;
}
@keyframes dash {
100% {stroke-dasharray:380,0;}
}
@keyframes fill-path {
to {fill:gold; stroke:#151515;}
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="150" viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="100%" height="100%"  />
<g id="svgGroup" transform="translate(30 10)" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt"  fill="#151515">

<path class="v"    d="M 21.56 63.6 Q 19.56 56.9 18.36 49.8 Q 17.16 42.7 16.26 35.5 Q 15.56 30.2 14.66 24.9 Q 13.76 19.6 11.86 13.9 Q 11.662 13.406 11.66 13.351 A 0.029 0.029 0 0 1 11.66 13.35 A 0.045 0.045 0 0 1 11.671 13.324 Q 11.707 13.277 11.86 13.2 Q 12.06 13.2 12.56 13.7 Q 14.045 15.185 15.205 17.819 A 26.507 26.507 0 0 1 16.11 20.2 Q 17.56 24.6 18.61 29.55 Q 19.66 34.5 20.36 39.15 Q 20.986 43.31 21.452 45.989 A 139.524 139.524 0 0 0 21.56 46.6 Q 22.06 48.9 22.41 51.3 Q 22.76 53.7 22.96 56.1 A 38.83 38.83 0 0 1 24.225 52.141 A 45.407 45.407 0 0 1 24.86 50.55 Q 26.06 47.7 27.31 45 A 107.653 107.653 0 0 1 29.029 41.453 A 90.995 90.995 0 0 1 29.81 39.95 A 129.689 129.689 0 0 0 30.684 38.279 Q 31.36 36.963 31.86 35.9 A 102.376 102.376 0 0 1 35.994 27.987 A 112.746 112.746 0 0 1 36.66 26.85 A 120.636 120.636 0 0 1 38.629 23.641 Q 40.223 21.138 41.66 19.2 A 46.678 46.678 0 0 1 41.873 18.919 Q 42.549 18.03 42.654 18.001 A 0.024 0.024 0 0 1 42.66 18 A 0.382 0.382 0 0 1 42.765 18.204 Q 42.799 18.383 42.71 18.65 A 16.089 16.089 0 0 1 42.503 19.232 A 19.442 19.442 0 0 1 42.36 19.6 Q 40.36 26.8 36.91 33.6 Q 33.46 40.4 29.96 47.3 Q 27.96 51.1 25.96 55 Q 23.96 58.9 22.96 63.7 Q 22.775 64.718 22.461 65.008 A 0.526 0.526 0 0 1 22.41 65.05 A 0.165 0.165 0 0 1 22.339 65.08 Q 22.041 65.127 21.643 63.873 A 13.432 13.432 0 0 1 21.56 63.6 Z M 24.723 78.444 A 1.66 1.66 0 0 0 24.66 78.4 Q 21.76 76 19.51 72.75 Q 17.26 69.5 15.56 65.75 Q 13.86 62 12.66 58.05 A 77.373 77.373 0 0 1 12.368 57.065 A 69.92 69.92 0 0 1 10.76 50.3 Q 9.66 44.4 9.11 38.15 Q 8.56 31.9 7.76 25.95 A 85.895 85.895 0 0 0 7.492 24.105 A 76.478 76.478 0 0 0 5.41 14.65 A 33.83 33.83 0 0 0 5.158 13.821 A 29.71 29.71 0 0 0 0.76 5.1 A 2.276 2.276 0 0 0 0.756 5.091 Q 0.656 4.893 0.46 4.6 A 1.588 1.588 0 0 0 0.421 4.544 Q 0.276 4.346 0.189 4.38 A 0.087 0.087 0 0 0 0.16 4.4 Q -0.04 4.6 0.01 4.75 A 1.815 1.815 0 0 0 0.036 4.823 Q 0.083 4.947 0.16 5.1 A 45.161 45.161 0 0 1 1.398 8.52 A 53.769 53.769 0 0 1 2.96 14.75 A 173.76 173.76 0 0 1 3.444 17.406 A 196.485 196.485 0 0 1 4.71 25.75 Q 5.46 31.5 6.06 37.5 Q 6.66 43.5 7.76 49.5 Q 8.56 53.8 9.76 58.2 Q 10.96 62.6 12.91 66.5 Q 14.86 70.4 17.66 73.55 Q 20.46 76.7 24.36 78.5 A 1.752 1.752 0 0 0 24.449 78.556 Q 24.683 78.692 24.81 78.65 A 0.156 0.156 0 0 0 24.819 78.647 Q 24.935 78.6 24.723 78.444 Z M 49.459 15.876 A 27.355 27.355 0 0 0 47.76 10.4 A 6.894 6.894 0 0 0 47.702 10.305 Q 47.509 9.995 47.411 9.922 A 0.092 0.092 0 0 0 47.36 9.9 Q 47.179 9.809 47.326 10.54 A 8.287 8.287 0 0 0 47.36 10.7 Q 48.06 14.2 47.91 17.85 Q 47.76 21.5 47.01 25.2 Q 46.26 28.9 45.06 32.4 Q 43.86 35.9 42.36 39.1 Q 40.06 44.2 37.21 49.15 Q 34.36 54.1 31.91 59 A 80.178 80.178 0 0 0 31.311 60.224 A 71.886 71.886 0 0 0 27.86 68.75 Q 26.26 73.6 26.46 78.4 A 0.593 0.593 0 0 0 26.47 78.512 Q 26.51 78.72 26.71 78.8 A 0.259 0.259 0 0 0 26.723 78.805 Q 26.924 78.873 27.092 78.551 A 1.659 1.659 0 0 0 27.16 78.4 A 51.038 51.038 0 0 1 27.902 76.026 A 58.843 58.843 0 0 1 30.41 69.85 Q 32.46 65.5 34.86 60.9 Q 37.26 56.3 39.81 51.5 Q 42.36 46.7 44.66 41.7 Q 46.36 38 47.71 34.1 Q 49.06 30.2 49.61 26.25 A 34.966 34.966 0 0 0 49.946 21.422 A 34.791 34.791 0 0 0 49.81 18.35 A 24.051 24.051 0 0 0 49.459 15.876 Z M 22.61 74.3 A 164.382 164.382 0 0 0 22.806 74.506 Q 23.623 75.363 24.16 75.9 Q 24.66 76.4 24.96 76.4 Q 25.206 76.4 25.25 75.929 A 2.465 2.465 0 0 0 25.26 75.7 A 6.094 6.094 0 0 1 25.264 75.496 Q 25.292 74.649 25.55 73.457 A 24.564 24.564 0 0 1 25.86 72.2 Q 26.46 70 27.41 67.35 Q 28.36 64.7 29.46 61.9 Q 30.56 59.1 31.56 56.65 A 123.907 123.907 0 0 1 32.165 55.192 Q 32.81 53.669 33.36 52.5 Q 33.973 51.198 34.292 50.542 A 35.463 35.463 0 0 1 34.46 50.2 Q 35.06 49.1 35.81 47.5 A 58.031 58.031 0 0 0 35.997 47.098 A 63.936 63.936 0 0 0 37.26 44.15 Q 37.96 42.4 38.61 40.8 A 64.662 64.662 0 0 0 38.992 39.839 Q 39.171 39.378 39.325 38.956 A 35.196 35.196 0 0 0 39.66 38 Q 39.76 37.7 40.01 36.85 A 4.334 4.334 0 0 0 40.051 36.703 Q 40.233 35.991 39.96 35.9 Q 39.793 35.816 39.346 36.292 A 6.152 6.152 0 0 0 39.16 36.5 A 64.302 64.302 0 0 1 38.954 36.74 Q 38.639 37.104 38.467 37.289 A 4.338 4.338 0 0 1 38.36 37.4 A 145.227 145.227 0 0 0 37.164 39.109 A 163.227 163.227 0 0 0 32.06 47 Q 28.96 52.1 26.66 57.2 Q 25.56 59.7 24.71 62.7 A 17.334 17.334 0 0 0 24.234 64.967 Q 24.022 66.444 24.022 68.081 A 26.995 26.995 0 0 0 24.06 69.5 Q 24.06 69.8 24.11 70.45 Q 24.16 71.1 24.21 71.8 A 90.203 90.203 0 0 0 24.217 71.892 Q 24.24 72.213 24.263 72.501 A 53.972 53.972 0 0 0 24.31 73.05 Q 24.349 73.478 24.297 73.573 A 0.043 0.043 0 0 1 24.26 73.6 Q 24.174 73.686 23.683 72.998 A 15.202 15.202 0 0 1 23.51 72.75 A 11.128 11.128 0 0 1 23.489 72.719 Q 22.85 71.779 22.26 70.5 A 25.972 25.972 0 0 0 22.125 70.157 A 23.298 23.298 0 0 0 21.16 68.05 A 55.166 55.166 0 0 0 21.141 68.013 Q 20.844 67.446 20.499 66.818 A 90.306 90.306 0 0 0 19.76 65.5 A 1.31 1.31 0 0 1 19.662 65.389 Q 19.491 65.173 19.26 64.75 A 33.222 33.222 0 0 1 19.185 64.612 A 36.836 36.836 0 0 1 18.66 63.6 A 7.217 7.217 0 0 0 18.388 63.104 A 5.645 5.645 0 0 0 18.01 62.55 A 7.35 7.35 0 0 0 17.954 62.479 Q 17.719 62.184 17.611 62.119 A 0.105 0.105 0 0 0 17.56 62.1 A 0.157 0.157 0 0 0 17.509 62.129 Q 17.312 62.293 17.46 63.181 A 8.735 8.735 0 0 0 17.51 63.45 A 15.788 15.788 0 0 0 17.619 63.952 Q 17.867 65.013 18.31 66.3 A 45.816 45.816 0 0 0 18.379 66.5 A 49.945 49.945 0 0 0 19.56 69.55 Q 20.019 70.633 20.436 71.436 A 14.157 14.157 0 0 0 20.86 72.2 Q 21.66 73.3 22.61 74.3 Z M 15.26 49.5 Q 15.26 49.8 15.21 50.75 A 4.633 4.633 0 0 1 15.185 51.048 Q 15.108 51.7 14.86 51.7 A 0.096 0.096 0 0 1 14.817 51.711 Q 14.639 51.711 14.389 51.031 A 6.78 6.78 0 0 1 14.36 50.95 Q 14.13 50.299 13.959 49.854 A 19.584 19.584 0 0 0 13.86 49.6 A 69.681 69.681 0 0 1 13.546 48.548 Q 13.409 48.077 13.263 47.553 A 135.968 135.968 0 0 1 12.96 46.45 Q 12.46 44.6 12.01 42.65 Q 11.56 40.7 11.21 38.8 A 40.93 40.93 0 0 1 10.983 37.445 Q 10.883 36.776 10.821 36.184 A 20.925 20.925 0 0 1 10.76 35.5 A 249.24 249.24 0 0 0 10.707 35.129 Q 10.621 34.534 10.463 33.455 A 2944.388 2944.388 0 0 0 10.36 32.75 Q 10.154 31.341 9.853 29.577 A 218.277 218.277 0 0 0 9.56 27.9 Q 9.06 25.1 8.41 21.9 Q 7.76 18.7 7.01 15.75 Q 6.26 12.8 5.46 10.45 Q 4.767 8.413 4.073 7.316 A 5.827 5.827 0 0 0 3.86 7 A 4.231 4.231 0 0 1 3.723 6.797 Q 3.448 6.36 3.517 6.169 A 0.184 0.184 0 0 1 3.56 6.1 A 0.33 0.33 0 0 1 3.638 6.041 Q 3.811 5.949 4.047 6.139 A 1.051 1.051 0 0 1 4.06 6.15 Q 4.29 6.341 4.461 6.504 A 5.149 5.149 0 0 1 4.56 6.6 Q 6.16 7.8 7.61 10 Q 9.06 12.2 10.26 14.7 Q 11.46 17.2 12.26 19.85 A 40.726 40.726 0 0 1 12.864 22.063 Q 13.11 23.08 13.266 23.998 A 22.925 22.925 0 0 1 13.36 24.6 A 132.724 132.724 0 0 1 14.395 33.443 A 154.737 154.737 0 0 1 14.66 37.1 Q 15.06 43.7 15.26 49.5 Z M 46.35 18.363 A 16.928 16.928 0 0 0 46.46 17.4 Q 46.66 14.5 46.31 12.9 Q 45.96 11.3 45.36 10.1 Q 45.26 9.9 44.86 9.45 A 2.765 2.765 0 0 0 44.74 9.323 Q 44.543 9.128 44.373 9.051 A 0.516 0.516 0 0 0 44.16 9 A 0.213 0.213 0 0 0 44.123 9.003 Q 43.97 9.03 44.06 9.3 Q 44.126 9.497 44.148 9.651 A 1.034 1.034 0 0 1 44.16 9.8 A 20.082 20.082 0 0 1 44.199 10.041 Q 44.417 11.458 44.417 12.812 A 16.59 16.59 0 0 1 44.41 13.3 A 42.946 42.946 0 0 1 44.351 14.603 A 51.164 51.164 0 0 1 44.16 16.9 Q 43.96 18.4 43.86 19.8 Q 43.76 21.2 43.46 22.8 Q 43.46 23.025 43.404 23.419 A 12.285 12.285 0 0 1 43.36 23.7 A 6.997 6.997 0 0 0 43.337 23.851 A 7.689 7.689 0 0 0 43.26 24.95 L 43.26 26.1 A 4.447 4.447 0 0 0 43.261 26.174 Q 43.268 26.6 43.36 26.6 A 0.187 0.187 0 0 0 43.466 26.633 Q 43.692 26.633 44.012 26.078 A 5.446 5.446 0 0 0 44.16 25.8 A 14.066 14.066 0 0 0 44.394 25.307 Q 44.777 24.46 45.16 23.35 A 23.578 23.578 0 0 0 45.415 22.566 A 27.173 27.173 0 0 0 46.01 20.25 A 33.904 33.904 0 0 0 46.16 19.501 Q 46.274 18.898 46.35 18.363 Z" id="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>

<path class="v" d="M 81.242 46.492 A 17.535 17.535 0 0 0 81.66 44.6 A 17.42 17.42 0 0 0 81.758 43.847 Q 82.062 41.011 81.31 38.8 A 13.334 13.334 0 0 0 80.503 36.901 A 9.939 9.939 0 0 0 78.96 34.7 Q 77.26 33 75.06 32.15 Q 72.86 31.3 70.36 31.25 A 16.67 16.67 0 0 0 70.027 31.247 A 17.238 17.238 0 0 0 65.36 31.9 Q 62.86 32.6 60.56 34 Q 58.16 35.5 56.26 37.45 A 33.362 33.362 0 0 0 55.341 38.431 A 28.936 28.936 0 0 0 52.96 41.45 A 33.953 33.953 0 0 0 52.129 42.726 A 28.55 28.55 0 0 0 50.61 45.5 A 64.591 64.591 0 0 0 50.35 46.055 Q 49.97 46.875 49.652 47.623 A 37.529 37.529 0 0 0 49.06 49.1 A 37.261 37.261 0 0 0 46.754 61.918 A 36.723 36.723 0 0 0 46.86 64.7 A 14.013 14.013 0 0 0 46.879 64.987 Q 46.946 65.873 47.131 66.852 A 23.716 23.716 0 0 0 47.56 68.7 Q 48.16 70.9 49.26 72.9 Q 50.36 74.9 52.11 76.45 A 8.406 8.406 0 0 0 53.656 77.536 A 9.471 9.471 0 0 0 56.36 78.5 A 3.359 3.359 0 0 0 56.782 78.612 Q 57.141 78.682 57.46 78.65 Q 57.96 78.6 57.96 78.4 Q 57.96 78.317 57.583 78.234 A 4.888 4.888 0 0 0 57.41 78.2 Q 56.86 78.1 56.36 77.8 A 15.449 15.449 0 0 1 54.031 76.124 A 11.151 11.151 0 0 1 51.66 73.25 Q 50.16 70.6 49.81 67.7 Q 49.46 64.8 49.81 61.8 Q 50.16 58.8 50.56 56.2 Q 50.96 53.5 51.91 50.8 Q 52.86 48.1 54.36 45.55 Q 55.86 43 57.91 40.75 Q 59.96 38.5 62.66 36.8 Q 66.86 34.1 70.76 33.75 A 9.515 9.515 0 0 1 71.611 33.711 Q 73.175 33.711 74.515 34.258 A 7.72 7.72 0 0 1 77.26 36.2 A 8.448 8.448 0 0 1 78.599 38.13 Q 79.294 39.496 79.606 41.232 A 17.362 17.362 0 0 1 79.86 44.3 Q 79.76 47.4 77.91 49.95 A 32.413 32.413 0 0 1 77.374 50.668 Q 76.605 51.669 75.845 52.487 A 17.304 17.304 0 0 1 74.26 54 A 3.254 3.254 0 0 0 74.207 54.054 Q 73.903 54.373 73.903 54.561 A 0.189 0.189 0 0 0 73.96 54.7 Q 74.16 54.9 74.56 54.6 Q 74.985 54.281 75.481 53.934 A 49.372 49.372 0 0 1 76.41 53.3 A 9.959 9.959 0 0 0 77.493 52.458 A 13.683 13.683 0 0 0 78.51 51.45 Q 79.56 50.3 80.41 48.65 A 9.72 9.72 0 0 0 80.618 48.221 Q 80.976 47.433 81.242 46.492 Z M 77.04 38.863 A 6.408 6.408 0 0 0 76.26 37.6 A 6.162 6.162 0 0 0 75.945 37.236 A 6.584 6.584 0 0 0 74.26 35.95 Q 73.06 35.3 71.51 35.2 A 6.973 6.973 0 0 0 71.061 35.186 Q 69.696 35.186 68.11 35.7 Q 66.954 36.075 65.661 36.802 A 21.872 21.872 0 0 0 64.06 37.8 Q 61.06 39.9 58.91 42.9 Q 56.76 45.9 55.56 49.4 A 21.351 21.351 0 0 0 55.55 49.43 Q 54.963 51.2 55.31 51.2 Q 55.595 51.2 56.376 50.274 A 17.798 17.798 0 0 0 56.76 49.8 Q 58.76 47 61.06 44.5 Q 63.36 42 66.26 40.3 A 24.101 24.101 0 0 1 67.438 39.642 Q 69.558 38.539 70.817 38.539 A 2.601 2.601 0 0 1 71.06 38.55 Q 72.66 38.7 73.86 39.9 A 3.677 3.677 0 0 1 74.824 41.619 Q 75.019 42.376 74.97 43.307 A 8.208 8.208 0 0 1 74.91 43.95 A 9.069 9.069 0 0 1 74.808 44.558 Q 74.331 46.92 72.56 49.4 A 19.671 19.671 0 0 1 72.333 49.715 A 17.596 17.596 0 0 1 69.91 52.4 A 30.834 30.834 0 0 1 68.818 53.335 A 24.963 24.963 0 0 1 67.06 54.65 Q 65.66 55.6 64.41 56.25 A 23.115 23.115 0 0 1 63.749 56.581 Q 62.912 56.983 62.26 57.2 A 9.896 9.896 0 0 0 62.095 57.26 Q 60.778 57.751 61.993 57.796 A 7.344 7.344 0 0 0 62.26 57.8 A 9.302 9.302 0 0 0 63.65 57.692 Q 64.83 57.514 66.114 57.041 A 18.969 18.969 0 0 0 68.51 55.95 A 19.918 19.918 0 0 0 71.423 54.035 A 24.277 24.277 0 0 0 74.86 50.7 A 14.685 14.685 0 0 0 75.835 49.393 A 11.658 11.658 0 0 0 77.06 47 Q 77.76 45.1 77.86 43.35 Q 77.894 42.763 77.865 42.205 A 8.858 8.858 0 0 0 77.51 40.1 A 8.751 8.751 0 0 0 77.04 38.863 Z M 73.164 42.266 A 2.781 2.781 0 0 0 72.56 41 Q 70.56 39 65.16 43.3 Q 62.26 45.6 60.31 48.85 Q 58.36 52.1 57.31 55.8 Q 56.26 59.5 56.16 63.3 A 31.958 31.958 0 0 0 56.149 64.141 A 28.901 28.901 0 0 0 56.86 70.6 A 5.889 5.889 0 0 0 56.965 70.989 A 4.63 4.63 0 0 0 58.51 73.3 A 5.385 5.385 0 0 0 59.722 74.032 A 6.193 6.193 0 0 0 61.51 74.5 A 8.371 8.371 0 0 0 62.461 74.553 Q 63.793 74.553 65.26 74.15 A 10.032 10.032 0 0 0 66.613 73.671 A 11.435 11.435 0 0 0 69.06 72.2 A 7.53 7.53 0 0 0 69.187 72.119 Q 69.848 71.688 69.71 71.55 A 0.133 0.133 0 0 0 69.692 71.535 Q 69.521 71.417 68.86 71.7 A 21.987 21.987 0 0 1 67.306 72.259 Q 66.571 72.491 65.923 72.625 A 8.801 8.801 0 0 1 64.66 72.8 A 11.046 11.046 0 0 1 64.507 72.808 Q 62.912 72.88 61.91 72.45 A 4.244 4.244 0 0 1 61.46 72.226 A 3.316 3.316 0 0 1 60.31 71.15 Q 59.76 70.3 59.66 69.4 Q 59.16 67.1 59.46 63.4 Q 59.76 59.7 60.86 55.9 Q 63.46 55.1 65.16 54.05 Q 66.037 53.509 66.94 52.794 A 26.025 26.025 0 0 0 68.66 51.3 Q 71.96 48.3 72.86 45.35 A 11.083 11.083 0 0 0 73.013 44.801 Q 73.384 43.316 73.164 42.266 Z M 70.563 74.115 A 10.743 10.743 0 0 0 71.56 72.9 A 9.767 9.767 0 0 0 71.649 72.764 Q 72.278 71.785 71.784 71.969 A 1.049 1.049 0 0 0 71.71 72 Q 71.06 72.3 70.56 72.6 Q 68.56 74.1 66.36 75 Q 65.123 75.506 63.632 75.728 A 16.831 16.831 0 0 1 61.16 75.9 A 5.178 5.178 0 0 1 60.922 75.894 Q 60.085 75.856 59.207 75.547 A 8.519 8.519 0 0 1 57.81 74.9 A 12.336 12.336 0 0 1 56.495 74.038 A 9.487 9.487 0 0 1 54.96 72.6 A 25.956 25.956 0 0 0 54.86 72.476 A 23.671 23.671 0 0 0 54.16 71.65 Q 53.833 71.282 53.506 71.349 A 0.589 0.589 0 0 0 53.36 71.4 Q 53.16 71.4 53.16 71.75 A 1.254 1.254 0 0 0 53.162 71.822 Q 53.18 72.141 53.36 72.5 Q 54.56 76 56.81 77.15 Q 59.06 78.3 61.66 78.3 Q 63.16 78.3 64.61 77.8 Q 66.06 77.3 67.41 76.55 A 14.414 14.414 0 0 0 67.946 76.237 A 12.542 12.542 0 0 0 69.81 74.85 A 13.469 13.469 0 0 0 70.563 74.115 Z M 70.16 43.7 A 0.387 0.387 0 0 0 69.796 43.48 Q 69.111 43.462 67.356 44.92 A 23.771 23.771 0 0 0 67.26 45 A 14.739 14.739 0 0 0 64.369 47.975 A 13.439 13.439 0 0 0 63.61 49.15 Q 62.26 51.5 61.26 54.3 A 22.704 22.704 0 0 0 64.355 52.534 A 20.734 20.734 0 0 0 64.76 52.25 A 91.682 91.682 0 0 0 66.957 50.623 A 78.661 78.661 0 0 0 67.76 50 A 7.254 7.254 0 0 0 69.615 47.48 A 9.017 9.017 0 0 0 69.96 46.6 A 11.205 11.205 0 0 0 70.157 45.946 Q 70.549 44.476 70.213 43.795 A 1.092 1.092 0 0 0 70.16 43.7 Z" id="1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>

<path class="v" d="M 98.46 44.7 Q 99.56 43.3 100.56 42.7 A 14.335 14.335 0 0 1 102.154 41.871 A 12.764 12.764 0 0 1 102.56 41.7 A 0.442 0.442 0 0 0 102.613 41.696 Q 102.741 41.68 103.06 41.6 A 0.879 0.879 0 0 1 103.157 41.581 Q 103.485 41.538 103.66 41.8 Q 103.83 42.054 103.64 42.381 A 1.236 1.236 0 0 1 103.56 42.5 Q 103.313 42.83 103.133 43.024 A 2.739 2.739 0 0 1 103.06 43.1 L 101.51 44.65 A 36.537 36.537 0 0 0 100.506 45.693 A 30.358 30.358 0 0 0 99.96 46.3 A 8.684 8.684 0 0 0 98.379 48.805 A 9.77 9.77 0 0 0 98.36 48.85 Q 97.76 50.3 97.46 51.8 Q 99.16 50 100.71 48.4 Q 102.26 46.8 104.06 45.4 Q 106.36 43.7 108.06 41 Q 109.76 38.3 110.46 33.1 A 1.881 1.881 0 0 1 110.57 32.869 Q 110.713 32.617 110.896 32.526 A 0.499 0.499 0 0 1 110.96 32.5 Q 111.228 32.411 111.257 33.042 A 3.552 3.552 0 0 1 111.26 33.2 Q 111.495 37.742 110.626 40.812 A 12.082 12.082 0 0 1 110.06 42.4 Q 108.56 45.8 105.56 48.1 Q 103.96 49.3 102.36 50.7 Q 100.76 52.1 99.31 53.8 A 19.571 19.571 0 0 0 97.636 56.095 A 24.567 24.567 0 0 0 96.66 57.8 A 26.504 26.504 0 0 0 95.47 60.441 A 35.197 35.197 0 0 0 94.56 63.1 Q 93.86 65.4 93.16 67.45 Q 92.46 69.5 91.66 71.4 A 2.089 2.089 0 0 1 91.567 71.664 Q 91.376 72.1 91.06 72.1 A 0.294 0.294 0 0 1 90.903 71.962 Q 90.782 71.759 90.763 71.282 A 4.672 4.672 0 0 1 90.76 71.1 A 28.016 28.016 0 0 1 90.608 68.196 A 28.149 28.149 0 0 1 91.41 61.55 Q 92.56 56.8 94.16 51.7 Q 94.86 49.2 95.81 46.7 A 13.043 13.043 0 0 0 96.549 43.649 Q 96.703 42.39 96.66 41 A 3.066 3.066 0 0 1 96.878 39.893 Q 97.033 39.492 97.297 39.078 A 6.182 6.182 0 0 1 97.56 38.7 A 12.135 12.135 0 0 1 99.06 37.052 A 14.384 14.384 0 0 1 99.76 36.45 Q 101.06 35.4 102.46 34.65 A 20.093 20.093 0 0 1 103.375 34.188 Q 103.815 33.98 104.207 33.827 A 8.596 8.596 0 0 1 104.86 33.6 A 3.942 3.942 0 0 1 105.04 33.545 Q 105.741 33.348 105.759 33.681 A 0.334 0.334 0 0 1 105.76 33.7 A 0.721 0.721 0 0 1 105.701 33.97 Q 105.608 34.201 105.364 34.481 A 4.197 4.197 0 0 1 105.16 34.7 Q 103.06 36.6 100.91 39.2 A 11.781 11.781 0 0 0 99.311 41.682 A 9.285 9.285 0 0 0 98.46 44.7 Z M 89.732 78.326 A 0.451 0.451 0 0 0 89.76 78.3 Q 89.96 78.1 89.76 78 A 0.584 0.584 0 0 1 89.759 77.999 Q 89.559 77.899 89.36 77.6 A 21.231 21.231 0 0 1 89.096 77.31 A 17.573 17.573 0 0 1 84.71 68.3 Q 84.319 65.911 84.319 63.648 A 24.169 24.169 0 0 1 84.86 58.5 Q 85.66 54.9 87.01 51.35 Q 88.36 47.8 89.26 44.35 A 29.799 29.799 0 0 0 89.376 43.892 A 26.685 26.685 0 0 0 90.16 37.55 A 11.797 11.797 0 0 0 89.77 34.545 A 13.797 13.797 0 0 0 88.26 31 A 1.169 1.169 0 0 1 88.242 30.982 Q 88.195 30.932 88.148 30.872 A 2.009 2.009 0 0 1 88.06 30.75 A 0.707 0.707 0 0 0 88.041 30.723 Q 87.95 30.6 87.86 30.6 A 0.822 0.822 0 0 0 87.75 30.645 Q 87.56 30.741 87.56 30.9 Q 88.06 33.8 87.56 36.95 A 43.002 43.002 0 0 1 87.427 37.739 A 47.168 47.168 0 0 1 86.06 43.35 Q 85.06 46.6 83.91 50.05 Q 82.76 53.5 81.96 57 Q 81.36 59.6 81.26 62.35 A 17.804 17.804 0 0 0 81.248 62.997 A 18.373 18.373 0 0 0 81.91 67.85 A 17.33 17.33 0 0 0 82.407 69.385 A 19.504 19.504 0 0 0 84.36 73.2 A 16.445 16.445 0 0 0 86.394 75.709 A 21.663 21.663 0 0 0 89.06 78 Q 89.56 78.3 89.61 78.35 A 0.053 0.053 0 0 0 89.649 78.367 Q 89.684 78.367 89.732 78.326 Z M 90.56 32.8 L 90.56 32.4 Q 90.96 32.1 91.46 32.6 Q 92.76 33.7 93.51 35.3 Q 94.26 36.9 94.61 38.65 A 15.392 15.392 0 0 1 94.916 41.674 A 14.482 14.482 0 0 1 94.91 42.1 A 18.957 18.957 0 0 1 94.818 43.511 Q 94.729 44.369 94.56 45.1 A 50.368 50.368 0 0 1 93.311 49.473 A 62.224 62.224 0 0 1 92.31 52.25 Q 90.86 56 89.06 59.2 Q 89.06 59.4 88.81 59.85 Q 88.642 60.152 88.407 60.251 A 0.628 0.628 0 0 1 88.16 60.3 A 0.144 0.144 0 0 1 88.044 60.234 Q 87.943 60.101 87.91 59.7 A 5.47 5.47 0 0 1 87.9 59.556 Q 87.873 59.075 87.96 58.9 A 17.154 17.154 0 0 1 87.999 57.797 Q 88.079 56.56 88.324 54.89 A 58.5 58.5 0 0 1 88.36 54.65 A 35.029 35.029 0 0 1 88.673 52.868 Q 88.843 52.036 89.039 51.328 A 15.553 15.553 0 0 1 89.36 50.3 A 5.169 5.169 0 0 0 89.444 50.015 Q 89.637 49.297 89.983 47.538 A 131.199 131.199 0 0 0 90.01 47.4 Q 90.46 45.1 90.81 42.25 A 55.05 55.05 0 0 0 91.166 38.088 A 48.847 48.847 0 0 0 91.21 36.75 A 18.417 18.417 0 0 0 91.213 36.403 Q 91.213 34.215 90.666 33.013 A 3.588 3.588 0 0 0 90.56 32.8 Z M 92.36 78.3 L 91.96 78.1 A 17.213 17.213 0 0 1 90.038 76.674 A 15.09 15.09 0 0 1 89.46 76.15 A 6.313 6.313 0 0 1 88.585 75.095 Q 88.023 74.256 87.56 73.1 Q 87.356 72.624 87.198 71.941 A 12.953 12.953 0 0 1 87.06 71.25 A 19.661 19.661 0 0 1 86.882 70.004 A 15.611 15.611 0 0 1 86.81 69.1 A 9.938 9.938 0 0 1 86.798 68.736 Q 86.789 68.043 86.888 67.513 A 4.135 4.135 0 0 1 86.91 67.4 A 1.888 1.888 0 0 1 86.97 67.18 Q 87.124 66.735 87.435 66.795 A 0.453 0.453 0 0 1 87.46 66.8 A 0.303 0.303 0 0 1 87.64 66.869 Q 87.863 67.034 88.11 67.6 A 10.158 10.158 0 0 1 88.634 69.1 A 9.384 9.384 0 0 1 88.66 69.2 Q 88.86 70.3 89.11 71.3 A 9.646 9.646 0 0 0 89.439 72.362 A 7.795 7.795 0 0 0 89.76 73.1 A 22.241 22.241 0 0 0 92.329 77.467 A 24.965 24.965 0 0 0 92.66 77.9 A 5.071 5.071 0 0 1 92.705 78.017 Q 92.831 78.354 92.778 78.395 A 0.028 0.028 0 0 1 92.76 78.4 A 0.851 0.851 0 0 1 92.454 78.341 A 1.045 1.045 0 0 1 92.36 78.3 Z M 109.06 33.5 Q 109.06 35.6 107.86 37.2 Q 106.66 38.8 104.96 39.9 A 0.801 0.801 0 0 1 104.892 39.941 Q 104.688 40.049 104.593 39.913 A 0.312 0.312 0 0 1 104.56 39.85 Q 104.46 39.6 104.46 39.5 A 1.845 1.845 0 0 1 104.525 39.036 Q 104.636 38.608 104.94 38.084 A 6.299 6.299 0 0 1 104.96 38.05 Q 105.46 37.2 106.11 36.25 Q 106.76 35.3 107.36 34.3 A 9.409 9.409 0 0 0 107.754 33.578 Q 107.93 33.217 108.044 32.886 A 4.538 4.538 0 0 0 108.16 32.5 A 1.022 1.022 0 0 1 108.228 32.4 Q 108.494 32.057 108.76 32.5 A 2.227 2.227 0 0 1 108.975 32.969 A 1.741 1.741 0 0 1 109.06 33.5 Z" id="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/> 

<path class="v" d="M 133.46 59.6 Q 132.16 62 130.56 64.75 A 23.654 23.654 0 0 1 129.57 66.317 Q 128.532 67.817 127.537 68.637 A 6.562 6.562 0 0 1 127.46 68.7 A 8.566 8.566 0 0 1 126.992 69.051 Q 125.984 69.749 125.476 69.559 A 0.567 0.567 0 0 1 125.36 69.5 A 2.161 2.161 0 0 1 125.017 69.206 Q 124.694 68.874 124.322 68.297 A 12.974 12.974 0 0 1 123.96 67.7 L 123.16 66.5 Q 122.86 66.6 122.86 67.2 A 3.133 3.133 0 0 0 122.937 67.907 A 2.682 2.682 0 0 0 123.06 68.3 A 11.597 11.597 0 0 0 123.407 69.3 Q 123.892 70.505 124.51 71.05 Q 125.309 71.755 126.771 71.355 A 5.469 5.469 0 0 0 126.96 71.3 Q 128.588 70.848 130.175 69.414 A 12.683 12.683 0 0 0 130.51 69.1 A 33.541 33.541 0 0 0 132.522 66.975 A 27.551 27.551 0 0 0 133.56 65.7 Q 136.56 61.6 138.31 57 Q 140.06 52.4 140.26 47.6 Q 140.46 43.2 139.16 41.9 A 3.272 3.272 0 0 0 137.996 41.133 Q 137.068 40.783 135.91 41.05 Q 133.96 41.5 131.71 43.15 Q 129.46 44.8 127.66 46.3 A 12.393 12.393 0 0 1 128.932 43.929 A 14.155 14.155 0 0 1 129.31 43.4 Q 130.36 42 131.71 40.95 Q 133.06 39.9 134.71 39.35 A 7.693 7.693 0 0 1 137.157 38.947 A 7.723 7.723 0 0 1 138.06 39 A 2.519 2.519 0 0 1 139.354 39.526 A 3.601 3.601 0 0 1 139.86 40 A 6.274 6.274 0 0 1 140.695 41.209 A 8.291 8.291 0 0 1 141.16 42.25 Q 141.66 43.6 141.81 45.4 A 18.793 18.793 0 0 1 141.874 46.961 A 20.423 20.423 0 0 1 141.76 49.1 Q 141.26 52.9 140.31 56.7 A 40.314 40.314 0 0 1 138.744 61.641 A 34.635 34.635 0 0 1 137.86 63.7 Q 137.66 64.2 137.21 65.1 A 6.087 6.087 0 0 0 137.089 65.357 Q 136.79 66.03 136.96 66.2 Q 137.16 66.4 137.91 65.55 Q 138.484 64.899 138.853 64.512 A 12.589 12.589 0 0 1 139.06 64.3 A 28.162 28.162 0 0 0 141.346 60.693 A 33.48 33.48 0 0 0 142.26 58.85 Q 143.66 55.8 144.41 52.6 Q 145.16 49.4 145.26 46.15 Q 145.344 43.433 144.868 40.961 A 20.984 20.984 0 0 0 144.66 40 A 6.606 6.606 0 0 0 144.136 38.539 A 4.196 4.196 0 0 0 142.21 36.6 A 6.704 6.704 0 0 0 139.238 35.925 A 7.975 7.975 0 0 0 138.16 36 Q 135.96 36.3 133.76 37.4 A 19.058 19.058 0 0 0 131.988 38.401 Q 130.948 39.069 130.16 39.8 Q 130.76 38.3 131.81 37.15 Q 132.86 36 134.21 35.15 Q 135.56 34.3 137.11 33.95 A 9.021 9.021 0 0 1 139.103 33.727 A 9.32 9.32 0 0 1 140.26 33.8 Q 143.06 34.1 144.51 36 Q 145.96 37.9 146.51 40.35 A 21.212 21.212 0 0 1 147.014 45.01 A 23.338 23.338 0 0 1 147.01 45.45 Q 146.976 47.272 146.87 48.692 A 33.198 33.198 0 0 1 146.76 49.9 Q 146.26 54.1 144.86 58.2 A 39.843 39.843 0 0 1 141.684 65.249 A 36.826 36.826 0 0 1 141.36 65.8 A 25.834 25.834 0 0 1 138.971 69.09 A 33.1 33.1 0 0 1 136.91 71.3 A 24.038 24.038 0 0 1 132.338 74.847 A 21.829 21.829 0 0 1 130.96 75.6 Q 127.76 77.2 124.36 77.25 A 9.057 9.057 0 0 1 124.227 77.251 Q 121.707 77.251 119.407 75.843 A 12.274 12.274 0 0 1 117.96 74.8 Q 115.96 73.1 115.11 70.25 A 34.308 34.308 0 0 1 114.262 66.785 A 28.334 28.334 0 0 1 113.96 64.8 A 35.493 35.493 0 0 1 113.743 60.878 A 36.215 36.215 0 0 1 114.11 55.75 A 51.044 51.044 0 0 1 115.277 49.929 A 43.242 43.242 0 0 1 116.06 47.3 Q 118.06 41.2 120.61 35 A 144.183 144.183 0 0 0 124.537 24.303 A 130.802 130.802 0 0 0 125.01 22.8 A 59.774 59.774 0 0 0 126.857 15.097 A 50.76 50.76 0 0 0 127.36 11.2 A 23.961 23.961 0 0 0 127.456 9.068 A 21.651 21.651 0 0 0 125.76 0.6 A 2.007 2.007 0 0 1 125.634 0.288 A 1.788 1.788 0 0 1 125.61 0.2 A 0.665 0.665 0 0 0 125.588 0.128 Q 125.561 0.056 125.524 0.024 A 0.096 0.096 0 0 0 125.46 0 Q 125.164 0.099 125.209 0.197 A 0.078 0.078 0 0 0 125.21 0.2 A 0.482 0.482 0 0 1 125.25 0.313 A 0.408 0.408 0 0 1 125.26 0.4 Q 125.86 5.2 124.86 10.4 Q 123.86 15.6 122.01 21.2 Q 120.16 26.8 117.86 32.75 Q 115.56 38.7 113.46 45 Q 112.06 49.5 111.21 54.6 A 32.23 32.23 0 0 0 110.772 59.908 A 34.08 34.08 0 0 0 111.16 65 Q 112.26 72.2 117.06 75.7 Q 121.86 79.2 129.06 78.4 Q 134.26 77.8 138.26 74.2 A 30.874 30.874 0 0 0 144.42 66.482 A 35.349 35.349 0 0 0 144.96 65.5 Q 146.96 61.6 148.41 57.25 Q 149.86 52.9 150.16 48.4 A 35.481 35.481 0 0 0 150.249 45.872 A 39.392 39.392 0 0 0 150.11 42.6 A 19.238 19.238 0 0 0 149.337 38.52 A 17.044 17.044 0 0 0 148.81 37.05 Q 147.76 34.5 145.71 32.85 A 7.836 7.836 0 0 0 143.086 31.486 Q 141.814 31.091 140.26 31 Q 138.503 30.912 136.4 31.75 A 14.902 14.902 0 0 0 135.81 32 A 15.165 15.165 0 0 0 133.993 32.96 Q 132.791 33.709 131.96 34.6 Q 132.86 31.6 133.61 28.45 A 66.585 66.585 0 0 0 134.507 24.051 A 57.225 57.225 0 0 0 134.76 22.4 A 38.347 38.347 0 0 0 135.066 19.286 Q 135.116 18.384 135.116 17.521 A 29.126 29.126 0 0 0 135.11 16.95 Q 135.06 14.4 134.36 12.6 Q 134.16 11.8 133.96 11.8 A 0.048 0.048 0 0 0 133.922 11.836 Q 133.86 11.969 133.86 12.6 A 42.933 42.933 0 0 1 131.934 24.21 A 40.387 40.387 0 0 1 131.76 24.75 Q 129.86 30.5 127.96 35.7 Q 126.46 39.9 124.81 44.05 Q 123.16 48.2 122.01 52.3 A 56.415 56.415 0 0 0 120.495 59.36 A 51.205 51.205 0 0 0 120.36 60.35 A 25.848 25.848 0 0 0 120.152 63.598 A 23.627 23.627 0 0 0 120.56 68 Q 120.66 68.4 120.91 68.95 A 3.112 3.112 0 0 0 121.002 69.137 Q 121.153 69.418 121.285 69.481 A 0.172 0.172 0 0 0 121.36 69.5 A 0.129 0.129 0 0 0 121.481 69.418 Q 121.54 69.297 121.51 69 Q 121.46 68.5 121.56 68 A 46.302 46.302 0 0 1 122.062 65.171 Q 122.585 62.644 123.46 59.55 Q 124.86 54.6 126.76 49.6 A 124.295 124.295 0 0 1 127.648 48.801 Q 128.441 48.094 129.41 47.25 Q 130.96 45.9 132.51 44.8 A 20.041 20.041 0 0 1 133.728 43.997 Q 134.346 43.623 134.919 43.349 A 10.537 10.537 0 0 1 135.36 43.15 Q 136.317 42.745 136.894 42.909 A 0.983 0.983 0 0 1 137.26 43.1 Q 138.06 43.9 137.86 46.05 A 21.851 21.851 0 0 1 137.53 48.275 Q 137.306 49.404 136.957 50.635 A 35.902 35.902 0 0 1 136.91 50.8 Q 136.16 53.4 135.16 55.85 Q 134.336 57.869 133.715 59.107 A 18.924 18.924 0 0 1 133.46 59.6 Z M 130.56 23.7 Q 131.16 21.6 131.51 18.65 A 38.916 38.916 0 0 0 131.782 14.061 A 38.698 38.698 0 0 0 131.76 12.75 A 28.008 28.008 0 0 0 131.251 8.239 A 25.051 25.051 0 0 0 131.01 7.15 A 14.045 14.045 0 0 0 130.403 5.24 Q 129.852 3.875 129.06 2.9 A 5.087 5.087 0 0 1 128.81 2.63 A 6.126 6.126 0 0 1 128.66 2.45 A 1.026 1.026 0 0 0 128.554 2.335 Q 128.407 2.2 128.26 2.2 A 0.112 0.112 0 0 0 128.144 2.287 Q 128.078 2.495 128.36 3.2 Q 129.162 4.981 129.011 8.309 A 27.475 27.475 0 0 1 128.96 9.15 Q 128.66 13.1 127.76 17.6 Q 126.86 22.1 125.66 26.4 A 112.664 112.664 0 0 1 124.93 28.912 Q 124.199 31.311 123.552 32.968 A 31.38 31.38 0 0 1 123.46 33.2 A 29.873 29.873 0 0 0 123.003 34.334 Q 122.761 34.969 122.512 35.695 A 58.051 58.051 0 0 0 122.21 36.6 Q 121.56 38.6 120.96 40.65 Q 120.36 42.7 119.81 44.65 Q 119.26 46.6 118.96 48 A 4.666 4.666 0 0 1 118.947 48.332 Q 118.923 48.665 118.855 49.114 A 18.036 18.036 0 0 1 118.81 49.4 A 14.132 14.132 0 0 0 118.779 49.591 Q 118.68 50.244 118.747 50.296 A 0.021 0.021 0 0 0 118.76 50.3 A 0.511 0.511 0 0 0 118.874 50.332 Q 119.235 50.385 119.512 49.825 A 2.804 2.804 0 0 0 119.61 49.6 A 7.102 7.102 0 0 1 119.761 49.24 Q 119.997 48.719 120.209 48.539 A 0.547 0.547 0 0 1 120.26 48.5 Q 123.06 42.8 125.81 36.45 Q 128.56 30.1 130.56 23.7 Z M 119.86 71.3 Q 120.76 72.8 122.16 73.75 Q 123.56 74.7 124.96 75 Q 125.46 75.1 126.06 75.25 Q 126.66 75.4 126.66 75.8 Q 126.56 76.1 125.76 76.3 A 3.246 3.246 0 0 1 125.307 76.378 A 4.346 4.346 0 0 1 124.86 76.4 Q 123.16 76.3 121.51 75.8 Q 119.86 75.3 118.06 72.9 Q 116.86 71.3 116.31 69.3 A 19.803 19.803 0 0 1 115.816 66.996 A 16.05 16.05 0 0 1 115.66 65.5 Q 115.568 63.847 115.772 62.7 A 6.803 6.803 0 0 1 115.81 62.5 Q 116.041 61.392 116.485 61.392 A 0.384 0.384 0 0 1 116.56 61.4 A 0.074 0.074 0 0 1 116.609 61.426 Q 116.692 61.508 116.822 61.847 A 6.317 6.317 0 0 1 116.86 61.95 A 7.165 7.165 0 0 1 117.025 62.47 Q 117.101 62.738 117.167 63.043 A 12.588 12.588 0 0 1 117.21 63.25 Q 117.36 64 117.51 64.65 Q 117.657 65.288 117.756 65.589 A 3.264 3.264 0 0 0 117.76 65.6 A 133.127 133.127 0 0 0 117.954 66.413 Q 118.235 67.575 118.46 68.4 A 6.222 6.222 0 0 0 118.717 69.135 Q 119.034 69.9 119.622 70.902 A 25.797 25.797 0 0 0 119.86 71.3 Z" id="3" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></g></svg>
```