# Анимированная надпись (handwriting) на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, inkscape

При входе на сайт https://www.romboats.com/en заинтересовала первая страница (заставка), анимированное написание текста прописными буквами. Искала примеры, как сделать что-то подобное, но не нашла. Именно прописными буквами. Подскажите, кто знает или сталкивался с этим, как это сделать?

Comment: Просмотрите внимательно вопросы и ответы этого человека - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt  Он практикует как раз подобное, т.е. SVG. А на том сайте надпись сделана именно по этой технологии (и реализация кривая там, кстати ;-)

Comment: Погуглите в сторону `Handwriting Animation with SVG`, и найдете примеры и обучающее видео, как делать подобные анимации. @UModeL `и реализация кривая там, кстати`... там вообще весь сайт кривой. Держу пари, что разраб делал все на OS X, и даже не видел свое интерактивное уродство на Windows.

Comment: если необходимо будет сделать сложную анимацию, то это GSAP. так можно и нагуглить примеров - `GSAP handwriting`.

Comment: @Гузель Заитова что-то не заглядываете за ответом, а он вас ждёт уже давно :)

Answer (score 5):

Основная идея анимации рукописного шрифта (handwriting) заключается в анимации средней (осевой) линии каждой буквы.
Эта средняя линия должна иметь достаточную ширину, чтобы перекрывать самые широкие места контуров букв, но не задевать соседние контуры той же буквы или соседней буквы.

### Техника создания handwriting анимации по шагам:

***1. Создание контуров рукописного шрифта.***
Первый способ - это  выбрать подходящий шрифт в утилите [Google font to SVG path](https://danmarshall.github.io/google-font-to-svg-path/)

Не забудьте поставить галочку `separate characters:`, чтобы для каждой буквы был свой, отдельный path.

Например, выбран шрифт Sacramento

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="197.2" height="76.8" viewBox="0 0 197.2 76.8">
  <g stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.3" fill="none" style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.3;stroke:#000">
    <path d="M50.7 46.4L50.7 47.9A53.5 53.5 0 0 1 50.2 55.4 45.6 45.6 0 0 1 49.5 59.1Q48.3 64.4 45.7 68.2A19 19 0 0 1 38.7 74.3 18.6 18.6 0 0 1 33.8 76.1Q31.6 76.5 29.1 76.6A32.6 32.6 0 0 1 28.4 76.6 22.6 22.6 0 0 1 22.4 75.8 24.9 24.9 0 0 1 16.9 73.5Q14.3 72.1 12.3 70.2A16.8 16.8 0 0 1 10 67.5 14.6 14.6 0 0 1 9.1 66 1.6 1.6 0 0 1 8.8 65.2 1.9 1.9 0 0 1 8.8 65.1 1.7 1.7 0 0 1 9.2 64.1 2.3 2.3 0 0 1 9.4 63.9 1.7 1.7 0 0 1 10.5 63.3 2.3 2.3 0 0 1 10.7 63.3 2 2 0 0 1 11.4 63.5Q11.9 63.7 12.2 64.1A2.3 2.3 0 0 1 12.3 64.3 14.7 14.7 0 0 0 14.7 67.4 16.7 16.7 0 0 0 15.1 67.8 18.1 18.1 0 0 0 18.9 70.5 20.4 20.4 0 0 0 23.5 72.3Q25.9 72.9 28.4 72.9A23.7 23.7 0 0 0 32.4 72.6Q34.6 72.2 36.5 71.4A14.3 14.3 0 0 0 37 71.2Q40.5 69.4 42.8 66.1 45 62.8 46 58.2A41.8 41.8 0 0 0 46.8 53 55.6 55.6 0 0 0 47.1 47.9L47.1 45.9A7.9 7.9 0 0 1 45.8 45.4 5.7 5.7 0 0 1 44.5 44.4 3.2 3.2 0 0 1 43.5 42.1 4.1 4.1 0 0 1 43.5 42Q43.5 40.6 44.4 39.6A5.5 5.5 0 0 1 45.6 38.6Q46.2 38.1 47.1 37.8A50 50 0 0 1 47.1 35.6Q47.2 34.5 47.3 33.4 47.6 29.9 48.4 27.1A30.6 30.6 0 0 1 49.2 24.5 22.6 22.6 0 0 1 50.3 22.2Q51.4 20.1 52.5 18.7 53.4 17.5 54.2 16.7A15.9 15.9 0 0 1 54.7 16.2 22.2 22.2 0 0 1 55.3 15.7Q55.9 15.2 56.3 14.9A5.8 5.8 0 0 1 56.4 14.8Q57.1 14.4 57.2 14.4A0.4 0.4 0 0 1 57.2 14.4 1.4 1.4 0 0 1 57.7 14.2Q57.8 14.2 58 14.2A2.4 2.4 0 0 1 58.1 14.2 1.9 1.9 0 0 1 59.4 14.7 1.7 1.7 0 0 1 59.9 15.9 2.3 2.3 0 0 1 59.9 16 2 2 0 0 1 59.8 16.8Q59.6 17.2 59.1 17.5A2.3 2.3 0 0 1 59 17.6Q58.8 17.7 57.8 18.5A550.4 550.4 0 0 0 57.7 18.6Q56.5 19.4 55.2 21.2A16.8 16.8 0 0 0 54.2 22.8Q53.7 23.7 53.2 24.7A35.2 35.2 0 0 0 52.5 26.1 18.9 18.9 0 0 0 51.6 29.1Q51.3 30.5 51.1 32.1A36.2 36.2 0 0 0 50.9 33.7 16.8 16.8 0 0 0 50.8 35.3Q50.8 36 50.7 36.8A52.8 52.8 0 0 1 52.1 36.7 59.2 59.2 0 0 1 52.6 36.6 24.8 24.8 0 0 1 53.8 36.6 29.5 29.5 0 0 1 54.6 36.6 29.1 29.1 0 0 1 61.4 37.4 25.7 25.7 0 0 1 66 38.9 22.9 22.9 0 0 1 67.4 39.6 32.7 32.7 0 0 0 72.6 37Q76 34.9 78.2 32.1A16.3 16.3 0 0 0 82 21.6Q82 17.3 79.8 14A16.7 16.7 0 0 0 75.9 9.7 20.9 20.9 0 0 0 73.8 8.4 27.8 27.8 0 0 0 69.3 6.2 37.9 37.9 0 0 0 64.5 4.8 48.9 48.9 0 0 0 57.7 3.8 61.7 61.7 0 0 0 52.7 3.6Q47.1 3.6 41.2 4.5 35.4 5.3 30 7A60.3 60.3 0 0 0 19.7 11.3 41.8 41.8 0 0 0 14 14.9 35.6 35.6 0 0 0 11.4 17.1 26.4 26.4 0 0 0 6.6 23 24.4 24.4 0 0 0 5.8 24.5 19.2 19.2 0 0 0 3.7 33.3 17.2 17.2 0 0 0 4 36.4 12.9 12.9 0 0 0 4.9 39.4 13.6 13.6 0 0 0 7 42.7 12.3 12.3 0 0 0 8.2 43.9Q10.2 45.7 12.8 46.6A16.9 16.9 0 0 0 18.4 47.5 29.1 29.1 0 0 0 21.2 47.3Q22.9 47.2 24.4 46.8 26.3 46.3 27.8 45.7A18.6 18.6 0 0 0 28.7 45.3 22.8 22.8 0 0 0 29.7 44.8Q30.7 44.3 31.3 43.9A6.2 6.2 0 0 0 31.4 43.8 133.6 133.6 0 0 0 31.6 43.6Q32.3 43.1 32.4 43A149.4 149.4 0 0 0 32.7 42.7Q32.9 42.6 33 42.5A253.4 253.4 0 0 0 33.2 42.4 1.7 1.7 0 0 1 33.6 42.2 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 34.1 42.1 1.8 1.8 0 0 1 35.4 42.6Q35.9 43.1 35.9 43.9A1.8 1.8 0 0 1 35.8 44.5 1.6 1.6 0 0 1 35.4 45.2Q35.3 45.3 34.2 46.1A319.7 319.7 0 0 1 34.1 46.2 10.6 10.6 0 0 1 33.3 46.8Q32.4 47.5 31 48.1A33.2 33.2 0 0 1 30.8 48.2 23.6 23.6 0 0 1 28.8 49.1Q27.7 49.6 26.4 49.9A43.8 43.8 0 0 1 25.6 50.2 22.2 22.2 0 0 1 22.2 50.9Q20.6 51.1 18.7 51.1A36.1 36.1 0 0 1 18.5 51.1 20.4 20.4 0 0 1 11.4 49.9 17.8 17.8 0 0 1 5.5 46.3 16.6 16.6 0 0 1 1.6 41 19 19 0 0 1 1.5 40.7 16.7 16.7 0 0 1 0.2 36 21.3 21.3 0 0 1 0 33.3Q0 28.6 1.9 24.3 3.8 20.1 7.3 16.4A38.4 38.4 0 0 1 12.7 11.6 46 46 0 0 1 15.6 9.6 56.7 56.7 0 0 1 23.7 5.5 65.2 65.2 0 0 1 26.2 4.5 70.2 70.2 0 0 1 35.9 1.7 80.5 80.5 0 0 1 38.8 1.2Q45.5 0 52.6 0A64.1 64.1 0 0 1 60.4 0.5 51 51 0 0 1 65.9 1.4 41.1 41.1 0 0 1 71.5 3.2 30.8 30.8 0 0 1 76.4 5.6 22.2 22.2 0 0 1 80.8 9.1 18.9 18.9 0 0 1 83.3 12.2 16.3 16.3 0 0 1 85.7 20.2 19.7 19.7 0 0 1 85.7 21.1 20.3 20.3 0 0 1 81.9 33.1 24.7 24.7 0 0 1 76.5 38.6Q74 40.5 70.8 42A17.1 17.1 0 0 1 75 47.4 29 29 0 0 1 77.2 53 26.8 26.8 0 0 1 77.3 53.6 40.5 40.5 0 0 1 78.1 57.4 33.7 33.7 0 0 1 78.3 59.5 284.8 284.8 0 0 1 78.4 60.9Q78.5 62.8 78.6 64.3 78.7 66.1 78.9 67.5A15 15 0 0 0 79.1 68.8 10.3 10.3 0 0 0 79.5 69.9Q79.7 70.4 79.9 70.9A4.8 4.8 0 0 0 80.3 71.5 4 4 0 0 0 81.4 72.5 3.7 3.7 0 0 0 82.2 72.8Q83.3 73.2 84.8 73.2A8.1 8.1 0 0 0 88.9 72.1Q90.7 71.1 92.2 69.5A21.3 21.3 0 0 0 94.8 66.1 44.8 44.8 0 0 0 95.9 64.4 33.2 33.2 0 0 0 96.8 62.7Q97.5 61.3 97.9 60.3A19.4 19.4 0 0 0 98 60.1 117.9 117.9 0 0 0 98.1 59.8Q98.4 59.1 98.4 59A0.1 0.1 0 0 0 98.4 59Q98.9 57.8 100.1 57.8A2 2 0 0 1 100.7 57.9 1.7 1.7 0 0 1 101.4 58.3Q102 58.9 102 59.6 102 59.9 101.9 60.2A5.3 5.3 0 0 1 101.9 60.3Q101.8 60.4 101.4 61.4A119.6 119.6 0 0 1 101.3 61.7 21.4 21.4 0 0 1 100.9 62.8Q100.6 63.2 100.4 63.8A46.7 46.7 0 0 1 99.8 64.9 33.4 33.4 0 0 1 98.7 66.8 45.7 45.7 0 0 1 97.4 68.8 23.9 23.9 0 0 1 94 72.7 17.8 17.8 0 0 1 89.6 75.6Q87.2 76.8 84.3 76.8 82.2 76.8 80.7 76.3A7.1 7.1 0 0 1 80 76 7.1 7.1 0 0 1 77.1 73.6 9.7 9.7 0 0 1 76.1 71.6 13 13 0 0 1 75.5 69.7 23.4 23.4 0 0 1 75.1 67.3Q75 66.2 74.9 64.9A38.5 38.5 0 0 1 74.9 64.5 121.2 121.2 0 0 0 74.9 63.5Q74.8 63.1 74.8 62.6A227.7 227.7 0 0 0 74.8 61.6 40 40 0 0 0 74.6 59.4 47.7 47.7 0 0 0 74.4 58 39.4 39.4 0 0 0 73.9 55.1 44.6 44.6 0 0 0 73.6 54.2 21.4 21.4 0 0 0 72.3 50.2 18.8 18.8 0 0 0 70.1 46.6 13.4 13.4 0 0 0 67 43.8 15.1 15.1 0 0 0 66.8 43.7Q63.1 44.9 59.1 45.6A51.4 51.4 0 0 1 50.7 46.4ZM50.7 40.4L50.7 40.4 50.7 42.8A56.1 56.1 0 0 0 56 42.5 61.7 61.7 0 0 0 56.8 42.4 45.4 45.4 0 0 0 60.5 41.9 37.2 37.2 0 0 0 62.6 41.4 100.3 100.3 0 0 1 61.1 40.9 92.4 92.4 0 0 1 61 40.9 14.1 14.1 0 0 0 60 40.6 16.7 16.7 0 0 0 59.4 40.5 23.2 23.2 0 0 0 58.4 40.3 30.6 30.6 0 0 0 57.3 40.2 18.6 18.6 0 0 0 56.3 40.1Q55.8 40.1 55.2 40.1A31.3 31.3 0 0 0 54.8 40.1Q53.1 40.1 51.8 40.2A15.2 15.2 0 0 0 50.7 40.4Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    <path d="M120.7 68.6Q119.5 68.6 118.6 68.4A14.3 14.3 0 0 1 116.8 71.1 11.6 11.6 0 0 1 114.4 73.3 11.3 11.3 0 0 1 111.7 74.7 12.8 12.8 0 0 1 111.4 74.8Q109.8 75.3 107.8 75.3A11.4 11.4 0 0 1 105.1 75 9.8 9.8 0 0 1 103.6 74.5 10.2 10.2 0 0 1 100.3 72.2 9.9 9.9 0 0 1 98.3 69.2 11.5 11.5 0 0 1 98.1 68.8 11.7 11.7 0 0 1 97.4 65.6 14.2 14.2 0 0 1 97.3 64.3 14.7 14.7 0 0 1 97.5 61.6 10.9 10.9 0 0 1 98.4 58.9 17.5 17.5 0 0 1 99.6 56.8 13.1 13.1 0 0 1 101 55Q102.5 53.5 104 52.7A12.8 12.8 0 0 1 104.6 52.4Q105.3 52.1 105.8 52A2 2 0 0 1 106.2 52Q106.7 52 107.1 52.2A1.2 1.2 0 0 1 107.4 52.4 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 107.8 53.1 2.2 2.2 0 0 1 107.8 53.6Q107.8 54.3 107.5 54.7A1.3 1.3 0 0 1 107.3 54.8Q106.9 55.2 106.2 55.5A10.2 10.2 0 0 1 106 55.6 7.5 7.5 0 0 0 105.3 56Q105 56.2 104.6 56.5A13 13 0 0 0 104.3 56.7 8 8 0 0 0 103.3 57.7 10.1 10.1 0 0 0 102.7 58.5 8.8 8.8 0 0 0 101.9 59.9 11.3 11.3 0 0 0 101.5 61Q101 62.5 101 64.3A9.4 9.4 0 0 0 101.2 66.5 8.3 8.3 0 0 0 101.5 67.3 7 7 0 0 0 102.4 69.1 6.4 6.4 0 0 0 102.9 69.7Q103.8 70.7 105.1 71.3 106.3 71.8 107.9 71.8A9.9 9.9 0 0 0 109.9 71.6Q111.3 71.3 112.4 70.6A6.3 6.3 0 0 0 112.5 70.5 8.6 8.6 0 0 0 115.3 67.2 12.8 12.8 0 0 1 110.6 62.9Q108.7 60.2 108.7 56.7A9.5 9.5 0 0 1 108.9 54.7Q109.2 53.2 110.1 52.1A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 111.5 50.9Q112.4 50.4 113.6 50.4A5.2 5.2 0 0 1 116.1 51Q117.3 51.7 118.2 53 118.9 54.2 119.5 55.9A16.8 16.8 0 0 1 119.6 56.5Q120.1 58.4 120.2 60.8A31 31 0 0 1 120.2 61.7Q120.2 63.2 119.8 64.9A3.6 3.6 0 0 0 120.4 65L121 65A12.1 12.1 0 0 0 122.6 64.9 9.1 9.1 0 0 0 124 64.6 7.8 7.8 0 0 0 126.4 63.4 8 8 0 0 0 127.8 62.1 9.6 9.6 0 0 0 128.3 61.4Q129.2 60.2 129.9 58.6 130.1 58.3 130.6 58A2.2 2.2 0 0 1 131.1 57.8 1.8 1.8 0 0 1 131.5 57.8 1.6 1.6 0 0 1 132.4 58 2.3 2.3 0 0 1 132.7 58.3 1.7 1.7 0 0 1 133.3 59.5 2.3 2.3 0 0 1 133.3 59.6 1.8 1.8 0 0 1 133.3 60Q133.2 60.2 133.1 60.4A3.2 3.2 0 0 1 133.1 60.5 16.1 16.1 0 0 1 132.9 60.9 13 13 0 0 1 132.7 61.3 20 20 0 0 1 130.8 64.1Q129.7 65.5 128.2 66.5A12.6 12.6 0 0 1 125.5 67.8 14.5 14.5 0 0 1 124.9 68.1Q123 68.7 120.7 68.6ZM112.4 56.3A7.9 7.9 0 0 0 112.5 57.6 9.6 9.6 0 0 0 112.6 58.3 8.9 8.9 0 0 0 113.3 60.1 10 10 0 0 0 113.4 60.3 10.2 10.2 0 0 0 114.6 62.2 7.4 7.4 0 0 0 116.4 63.7 14.2 14.2 0 0 0 116.6 61.8 13.1 13.1 0 0 0 116.6 61.7 19 19 0 0 0 116.4 59Q116.2 57.7 115.8 56.5 115.4 55.4 114.9 54.7A2.1 2.1 0 0 0 114.5 54.3 1.4 1.4 0 0 0 113.6 54 0.6 0.6 0 0 0 113.4 54Q113.3 54.1 113 54.2A3.5 3.5 0 0 0 112.8 54.4 1.1 1.1 0 0 0 112.6 54.8Q112.4 55.1 112.4 55.7A7 7 0 0 0 112.4 56.3Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    <path d="M141.5 68.9A117.8 117.8 0 0 0 141.1 69.6Q141.3 66 141.5 62.4A114.9 114.9 0 0 0 141.7 58.6 151 151 0 0 0 141.7 54.4 9.9 9.9 0 0 0 141.7 54.2 10.8 10.8 0 0 0 141.6 52.4 7.2 7.2 0 0 0 141.4 51.8 5.9 5.9 0 0 0 140.9 50.6 3.7 3.7 0 0 0 139.7 49.2 2.9 2.9 0 0 0 138.7 48.8 4.1 4.1 0 0 0 137.8 48.7 3 3 0 0 0 137.5 48.7Q136.3 48.9 135 50.1A10.7 10.7 0 0 0 133.9 51.2Q132.5 52.9 131 56A58.4 58.4 0 0 0 129.7 58.9 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 129.6 59.2 1.8 1.8 0 0 0 129.6 59.6 1.9 1.9 0 0 0 130.1 60.9 1.6 1.6 0 0 0 130.8 61.4 2 2 0 0 0 131.4 61.5 1.9 1.9 0 0 0 131.7 61.5 2 2 0 0 0 132.4 61.2 1.8 1.8 0 0 0 133.2 60.4Q134.9 56.1 136.1 54.4A29.1 29.1 0 0 1 136.2 54.2Q137 53 137.4 52.7A0.5 0.5 0 0 1 137.6 52.6 0.4 0.4 0 0 1 137.7 52.7Q137.9 53 138 53.8A10.4 10.4 0 0 1 138.1 54.4Q138.1 55.2 138.1 56.1 138 58.4 137.9 61A1309 1309 0 0 0 137.8 63.5 1079.7 1079.7 0 0 0 137.6 65.9Q137.6 67.4 137.5 68.6A848.9 848.9 0 0 1 137.5 69.9 725.1 725.1 0 0 0 137.5 70.1Q137.4 71.3 137.4 71.6A2.4 2.4 0 0 0 137.4 71.6 5.6 5.6 0 0 0 137.4 71.8Q137.4 72.3 137.5 72.8A3 3 0 0 0 138.1 73.9 2.1 2.1 0 0 0 138.5 74.3Q138.8 74.6 139.4 74.7A3.7 3.7 0 0 0 140.2 74.8Q141.2 74.8 142.2 74A3.5 3.5 0 0 0 142.4 73.8Q143 73.3 143.7 72.2A14.6 14.6 0 0 0 144.2 71.2 81.9 81.9 0 0 1 144.5 70.7Q145.2 69.2 146.2 67.3A167.8 167.8 0 0 1 148.5 63.1 130.3 130.3 0 0 1 149.7 61.2 100.4 100.4 0 0 1 150.8 59.4Q151.5 58.1 152.1 57.3A15.9 15.9 0 0 1 152.5 56.8Q153.1 56.1 153.6 55.6A3.2 3.2 0 0 1 154 55.3 3.8 3.8 0 0 1 154.3 55.2Q154.5 55.1 154.7 55A1.8 1.8 0 0 1 155.2 54.9 1.2 1.2 0 0 1 155.9 55.2 1.7 1.7 0 0 1 156.3 55.5Q156.6 55.9 156.7 56.7A5.8 5.8 0 0 1 156.7 57.3Q156.7 57.8 156.7 58.5A82.4 82.4 0 0 1 156.6 59 194.4 194.4 0 0 0 156.6 59.4Q156.6 59.8 156.6 60.4A333 333 0 0 0 156.5 61.6Q156.5 63 156.4 64.6A113.6 113.6 0 0 0 156.4 65 103 103 0 0 0 156.3 67.6 464.8 464.8 0 0 1 156.2 69 353.8 353.8 0 0 1 156.2 70.3Q156.1 71.5 156.1 72.3A5.8 5.8 0 0 0 156.1 72.5Q156.1 73 156.2 73.4A3.1 3.1 0 0 0 156.8 74.6 2.1 2.1 0 0 0 157.9 75.3 2.9 2.9 0 0 0 158.7 75.4 2.7 2.7 0 0 0 158.8 75.4 2.3 2.3 0 0 0 159.8 75.2Q160.1 75 160.4 74.7A4.8 4.8 0 0 0 160.8 74.4 5.9 5.9 0 0 0 161.1 74Q161.3 73.7 161.5 73.4A13.5 13.5 0 0 0 161.8 72.8Q162.3 72 162.8 70.9A370.8 370.8 0 0 0 163.2 70.2Q164.7 67.3 166.1 64.6 167.6 61.9 168.9 59.7A29.5 29.5 0 0 1 169.6 58.8Q170.6 57.3 171.6 56.3A6.5 6.5 0 0 1 172.3 55.7Q172.7 55.4 173 55.2A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 174.1 55 2.4 2.4 0 0 1 174.1 55Q174.3 55 174.5 55 174.7 55 174.9 55.1A1.6 1.6 0 0 1 175.1 55.3 1 1 0 0 1 175.1 55.3Q175.4 55.6 175.7 56.2 175.8 56.7 175.9 57.4A11 11 0 0 1 175.9 58.1 12.7 12.7 0 0 1 175.9 58.5Q175.8 59.2 175.7 60.3A52 52 0 0 1 175.6 61.2 32.4 32.4 0 0 0 175.5 63 41.1 41.1 0 0 0 175.4 65.6 21.9 21.9 0 0 0 175.4 66.1 19.7 19.7 0 0 0 175.7 69.1 9.3 9.3 0 0 0 175.9 69.9 7.6 7.6 0 0 0 176.8 72 6 6 0 0 0 178.9 74 5 5 0 0 0 179.7 74.4Q180.3 74.6 181 74.7A10.1 10.1 0 0 0 182.4 74.8 8.1 8.1 0 0 0 186.2 73.9 14.2 14.2 0 0 0 186.4 73.8 15.1 15.1 0 0 0 189.6 71.4 24.7 24.7 0 0 0 192.5 68.2Q193.8 66.4 194.7 64.8A41.1 41.1 0 0 0 195.2 64.1Q195.5 63.5 195.8 63A22 22 0 0 0 196.3 62Q196.7 61 197 60.6A21.7 21.7 0 0 1 197.1 60.4 2 2 0 0 0 197.1 60.2 1.7 1.7 0 0 0 197.2 59.7Q197.2 59 196.7 58.4A1.7 1.7 0 0 0 196 57.9 1.8 1.8 0 0 0 195.4 57.8Q194.8 57.8 194.4 58.1A1.8 1.8 0 0 0 194 58.4 2.1 2.1 0 0 0 193.7 58.9 30.5 30.5 0 0 1 193.4 59.5Q193.1 60.2 192.7 61A35.6 35.6 0 0 1 192.2 62 43.7 43.7 0 0 1 191.2 63.6 35.2 35.2 0 0 1 191.1 63.8 38.3 38.3 0 0 1 189.4 66.4 20.5 20.5 0 0 1 189 66.9 18 18 0 0 1 187.3 68.8 12.3 12.3 0 0 1 186.5 69.4 10.3 10.3 0 0 1 184.9 70.5 6.1 6.1 0 0 1 184.5 70.7 5.1 5.1 0 0 1 182.4 71.2Q181.8 71.2 181.3 71.1A2.4 2.4 0 0 1 180.6 70.7 2.8 2.8 0 0 1 179.6 69.4 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 179.3 68.6 7.5 7.5 0 0 1 179.2 67.6Q179.1 66.6 179.1 65.6 179.1 63.1 179.3 61.3A28.8 28.8 0 0 0 179.4 60.4 25 25 0 0 0 179.5 57.8 9.9 9.9 0 0 0 179.5 57.1 11.6 11.6 0 0 0 179.3 55.6Q179.1 54.4 178.4 53.4 177.8 52.5 176.8 51.9A3.9 3.9 0 0 0 176.3 51.7Q175.4 51.3 174 51.3A4.7 4.7 0 0 0 173.2 51.4Q172.1 51.6 170.8 52.2A5.9 5.9 0 0 0 170.5 52.4Q169.3 53.1 168.1 54.6A22.6 22.6 0 0 0 166.8 56.1Q166.4 56.7 165.9 57.5A34.5 34.5 0 0 0 165.2 58.6 151.9 151.9 0 0 0 164.3 60.2 182 182 0 0 0 163.4 61.9Q162.5 63.7 161.5 65.5A262.2 262.2 0 0 0 160.6 67.2 193.1 193.1 0 0 0 159.9 68.7 238.7 238.7 0 0 1 159.9 67.3 291.7 291.7 0 0 1 160 65.8 1057.6 1057.6 0 0 1 160 65.4 961.3 961.3 0 0 1 160.1 62.7 398.4 398.4 0 0 1 160.2 61.3 321.7 321.7 0 0 1 160.3 60Q160.4 58.7 160.4 58A12.2 12.2 0 0 0 160.3 57.2 10.3 10.3 0 0 0 160.1 55.4 7.9 7.9 0 0 0 159.8 54.6 6.3 6.3 0 0 0 159.2 53.3 4.5 4.5 0 0 0 157.7 51.9 3.7 3.7 0 0 0 156.6 51.4 5 5 0 0 0 155.5 51.3 4.6 4.6 0 0 0 155.1 51.3Q154 51.4 152.7 52.1 151.2 52.8 149.8 54.5 149 55.5 147.8 57.5A131.8 131.8 0 0 0 146.6 59.5 152.6 152.6 0 0 0 145.3 61.6Q144.1 63.8 142.9 66A328.6 328.6 0 0 0 142.9 66.1Q142.1 67.7 141.5 68.9Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Второй способ - получение path из векторного редактора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Последовательность действий:*
Выбрать шрифт, размер, написать слово и в меню редактора выбрать контур / оконтурить объект

***2. Создание средней линии контура букв***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью инструмента `Рисовать кривые Безье` наносите узловые точки и с помощью рычагов управления узловых точек, корректируете форму кривой.
Сохраняете файл и копируете path в другой svg файл для создания анимации.
Эти кривые будут служить маской для открытия рукописных букв.

***3. Создание анимационной формулы***

```
<mask id="mask_r">  
<path id="Stroke_r1" stroke-dasharray="0,183"  d="m138.6 141.9c0 0 0.8 2.2 2.1 0.5 2.3-3 1.9 0.3 2.8 2 1.2 2.2-1.9 2.8-2 3.8-3.2 19-5.9 29.2-9.4 47-0.1 0.7-0.4 2.1-0.6 4.6-0.1 1.9 1.2 5.3 1.2 5.3" >
<animate id="an_r" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="0s" dur="1.5s" values="0,183;183,0" fill="freeze" />
</path>
</mask>
```

Максимальную длину для буквы `R` - `183px` можно получить с помощью `getTotalLength()` метода JS

Длина средней линии растет от нуля до максимума, постепенно показывая   рукописную букву.
Тем самым создается эффект рукописного написания буквы.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" height="400" width="400" version="1.1" >
<defs> 
<g stroke="white" stroke-width="12" fill="none">
<mask id="mask_r">   
   <!-- Средняя линия для буквы R  -->
<path id="Stroke_r1" stroke-dasharray="0,183"  d="m138.6 141.9c0 0 0.8 2.2 2.1 0.5 2.3-3 1.9 0.3 2.8 2 1.2 2.2-1.9 2.8-2 3.8-3.2 19-5.9 29.2-9.4 47-0.1 0.7-0.4 2.1-0.6 4.6-0.1 1.9 1.2 5.3 1.2 5.3" >
         <!-- Анимация средней линии для показа рукописной буквы -->
<animate id="an_r" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="0s" dur="1.5s" values="0,183;183,0" fill="freeze" />
</path>
 
 <path id="Stroke_r2" stroke-dasharray="0,183" d="m119.8 153.9c0 0-0.8-3.7-0.4-5.4 0.4-1.6 1.6-3 2.7-4.2 1.2-1.4 2.8-2.4 4.3-3.4 1.4-1 3-1.8 4.5-2.7 2-1.2 4-2.5 6.1-3.4 2.5-1.1 5-2 7.6-2.7 2.4-0.6 4.9-1 7.3-1.2 2.5-0.2 5-0.2 7.5-0.1 2.1 0.1 4.2 0 6.3 0.4 1.9 0.4 3.8 1.1 5.5 2.1 1.7 1 3.4 2 4.5 3.6 1.1 1.7 1.7 3.8 1.8 5.8 0.1 2.9-0.7 6-2.1 8.5-1 1.9-2.8 3.4-4.5 4.8-2.1 1.8-4.5 3.3-6.9 4.6-2.5 1.4-5.1 2.8-7.8 3.7-2.9 1-6.7 4.7-9 2.2 0.1-1.8 2.9-3.9 4.2-3.9 2.8 0.2 3.5 4.5 4.9 6.9 1.5 2.4 2.5 5.2 3.9 7.6 0.9 1.6 2 3.2 3 4.8 1.2 1.9 2.3 3.8 3.6 5.5 1.1 1.5 2.2 3 3.6 4.2 1.4 1.2 3 2.6 4.8 3 1.2 0.3 2.5-0.1 3.7-0.4 1.1-0.3 2.1-0.8 3.1-1.3 1.1-0.6 2.1-1.1 3-1.9 0.8-0.8 1.6-1.7 2.1-2.7C188 187.1 188.7 184.5 188.7 184.5" >
  <animate id="an_r" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="0s" dur="1.5s" values="0,183;183,0" fill="freeze" /> 
 </path>
  
  <path id="Stroke_o1" stroke-dasharray="0,190"  d="m227 153.6c0 0-3.6 0.3-5.4 0.7-2 0.5-4 1.1-5.8 2.1-1.8 1-3.3 2.3-4.8 3.7-1.4 1.3-2.7 2.7-3.7 4.3-1.4 2.2-2.6 4.6-3.4 7-0.7 2.2-1.1 4.5-1.2 6.7-0.1 2.1 0.1 4.3 0.6 6.3 0.5 1.8 1.2 3.6 2.2 5.1 1 1.4 2.2 2.7 3.6 3.7 1.5 1.2 3.1 2.3 4.9 3 1.6 0.6 3.4 1 5.1 1 2.4 0.1 4.8-0.3 7-1 2.5-0.9 4.7-2.3 6.7-3.9 1.4-1.1 2.5-2.4 3.6-3.7 1.7-2 3.4-4 4.6-6.3 1.1-2.1 1.9-4.3 2.5-6.6 0.5-1.8 0.8-3.6 0.9-5.4 0.2-2.1 0-4.3-0.1-6.4-0.2-1.9-0.2-3.8-0.9-5.5-0.9-2.1-2.2-4.1-3.9-5.7-1.1-1.1-2.6-1.6-3.9-2.4-1.5-0.8-2.8-2-4.5-2.4-0.8-0.2-2.1-0.7-2.5 0-1 1.6 1.1 3.8 2.5 5.1 2.3 2 5.8 1.7 8.5 2.8 2.8 1.1 5.3 2.7 8.1 3.9 1.9 0.8 3.8 1.5 5.7 2.1 1.3 0.4 2.6 1 3.9 1.2 2 0.3 4 0.2 6 0 1.7-0.2 3.5-0.3 5.1-0.9 2.1-0.7 6-3.1 6-3.1">
   <animate id="an_o" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="an_r.end" dur="2s" values="0,190;190,0" fill="freeze" /> 
 </path>  
   <path id="Stroke_m1" stroke-dasharray="0,315" d="m275.7 150.7c0 0 0.8 6.8 0.8 10.2 0.1 3.2 0 6.4-0.2 9.6-0.3 3.9-0.8 7.8-1.2 11.7-0.3 3-0.4 6-0.7 9-0.2 1.7-2.3 4.4-0.7 4.9 2.8 1 3-5.1 4.5-7.6 1.9-3.3 3.6-6.7 5.4-10 1.2-2.1 2.4-4.2 3.6-6.3 1.3-2.3 2.4-4.7 3.7-6.9 1.3-2.1 2.5-4.1 4-6 1.3-1.5 2.6-3 4.2-4.2 1.1-0.9 2.4-1.5 3.7-2.1 1.4-0.6 2.8-1.1 4.3-1.3 0.8-0.1 1.8-0.6 2.4 0 1.4 1.3 0.2 3.8 0.1 5.7-0.2 3.4-0.8 6.7-1.2 10-0.4 3.1-0.9 6.1-1.3 9.1-0.4 2.9-0.7 5.8-1.2 8.7-0.4 2.3-1.2 4.6-1.6 6.9-0.3 1.5-2.1 3.9-0.7 4.5 3 1.2 3.9-5.1 5.7-7.8 1.3-2 2.5-4.1 3.7-6.1 1.7-2.8 3.2-5.7 4.9-8.5 1.4-2.3 2.9-4.6 4.4-6.8 1.7-2.3 3.5-4.6 5.3-6.8 1.6-2 3-4.3 5.1-5.7 1.9-1.3 4.3-2.1 6.6-2.5 1.5-0.3 3.6-1.1 4.7 0 2.8 3-0.2 8.2-0.6 12.3-0.5 4.6-1.6 9-2.1 13.6-0.3 2.8-0.7 5.6-0.6 8.5 0 2.6-0.9 5.8 0.8 7.6 1.1 1.2 3.2 1 4.9 0.8 3-0.3 5.8-1.7 8.3-3.4 2.8-1.9 5-4.6 7.2-7.2 2.1-2.4 3.9-5.1 5.7-7.8 2-2.8 3.9-5.7 5.7-8.7 2-3.2 5.7-9.7 5.7-9.7" > 
     <animate id="an_m" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="an_o.end" dur="2.5s" values="0,315;315,0" fill="freeze" /> 
 </path>  
 </mask> 
 </g>
 </defs>
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#002F8E"  />
   <g transform="translate(-50)"> 
     <!-- Контур буквы R -->
 <path id="r1" fill="white" mask="url(#mask_r)"  d="m119.8 153.9c-1.3-1.5-1.9-3.2-1.9-5.2 0-5.2 4.4-10 13.2-14.5 8.8-4.5 18.3-6.7 28.3-6.7 15.5 0 23.3 4.9 23.3 14.8 0 4.8-1.7 8.9-5 12.2-3.3 3.3-9.1 6.8-17.4 10.5 7.5 17 13.9 25.5 19.3 25.5 2.8 0 5.9-2 9.1-6 0.2 0.8 0.2 1.3 0.2 1.6 0 2.6-1.5 5.4-4.6 8.2-3.1 2.8-6.1 4.2-9 4.2-7.3 0-15.1-10-23.4-29.9-1.7 0.5-3.2 0.7-4.5 0.7-0.7 0-1.3-0.1-1.8-0.4 1.2-5.9 4.1-8.9 8.8-8.9 0.9 0 2.1 0.2 3.5 0.6 10.3-3.4 15.4-9.1 15.4-17.1 0-2.9-1.5-5.3-4.4-7.2-2.9-1.9-6.6-2.9-11.2-2.9-7.7 0-15.1 1.9-22.2 5.8-7.1 3.8-12.3 8.7-15.7 14.7zm16.9 49.1c-3.2 1.6-6.1 2.4-8.7 2.4-1.6 0-2.4-0.7-2.4-2 0-0.7 0.4-2.6 1.1-5.9l9-45.4c0.5-2.6 0.8-4.5 0.8-5.7 0-1.1-0.4-2.1-1.1-3 4.2-1.6 7-2.3 8.7-2.3 2 0 3 1.1 3 3.4 0 0.5-0.5 3.3-1.5 8.2l-8.3 41.7c-0.6 2.9-0.9 5-0.9 6.1 0 0.7 0.2 1.5 0.5 2.4zM249.6 164"/>
 
 <!-- Контур буквы O -->
 <path id="o1" fill="white" mask="url(#mask_r)"  d="m249.6 164c0.1 0.8 0.1 1.4 0.1 2 0 9-3.1 16.9-9.2 23.6-6.1 6.7-13.3 10.1-21.5 10.1-6.3 0-11.4-2-15.4-6-3.9-4-5.9-9.2-5.9-15.7 0-7.3 2.5-13.6 7.6-18.9 5.1-5.3 11.2-8 18.1-8 1.1 0 2.2 0.1 3.4 0.4-0.8-1.4-1.2-2.6-1.2-3.6 0-1.5 0.5-2.9 1.5-4.3 7.6 0.6 14 4.5 19 11.7 5.2 3.5 10.6 5.3 16.2 5.3 3.7 0 7.6-1.2 11.9-3.7l2.3 4c-5 3.5-10.1 5.2-15.3 5.2-3.5 0-7.4-0.7-11.8-2.2zm-10.6-4c-2.6-0.8-5-2-7.2-3.7-1.6-0.3-2.9-0.5-4-0.5-5.3 0-10 2.4-14.2 7.2-4.1 4.8-6.1 10.2-6.1 16.4 0 4.4 1.2 8.1 3.7 11 2.5 2.8 5.7 4.3 9.6 4.3 5.3 0 9.8-2.7 13.6-8 3.8-5.3 5.7-11.7 5.7-19.1 0-2.6-0.4-5-1.2-7.5z"/>
    
    <!-- Контур буквы M -->
  <path id="m1" fill="white" mask="url(#mask_r)" d="m279.3 182.1c11.3-23.7 21.2-35.6 29.8-35.6 3.8 0 5.7 2.7 5.7 8.2 0 2.3-0.8 7.6-2.4 15.8l-2.8 14.2c5.5-11.5 11.2-20.7 17.1-27.7 5.9-7 11.1-10.5 15.4-10.5 4.8 0 7.1 2.8 7.1 8.3 0 2-0.7 6.6-2.1 13.7l-1.5 7.3c-0.9 4.4-1.3 7.7-1.3 9.8 0 3.8 1.3 5.6 4 5.6 6 0 15.2-11.2 27.7-33.5l3.9 2.2c-13.6 26.4-25.4 39.7-35.5 39.7-6.5 0-9.7-4.2-9.7-12.7 0-2.8 0.6-7.3 1.9-13.5l1.3-6.5c0.9-4.4 1.3-7.1 1.3-8.2 0-1.3-0.7-2-2.1-2-3.4 0-9.4 6.7-18.1 20.1-7.9 12.2-11.9 19.2-11.9 21 0 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.2 1-0.4 0.1-1.2 0.3-2.3 0.6-0.5 0.2-1.2 0.2-2.1 0.2-2.9 0-4.4-1.4-4.4-4.2 0-0.8 0.5-3.4 1.4-7.6 0.3-1.5 0.7-3.2 1-4.9l2-9.9c1.4-7.2 2.2-11.5 2.2-12.9 0-2.1-0.8-3.1-2.3-3.1-3.4 0-8.3 6-14.9 18.1-6.5 12-9.8 19.2-9.8 21.5 0 0.7 0.3 1.3 0.8 1.9-1.7 0.8-3.3 1.1-4.7 1.1-3.2 0-4.9-1.7-4.9-5.2 0-0.4 0.5-5 1.4-13.6l1.1-10c0.4-3.5 0.6-6.7 0.6-9.7 0-3.7-0.8-6.5-2.3-8.2 3.6-1.3 6.2-2 7.7-2 2.8 0 4.1 1.6 4.1 4.9 0 1.2-0.4 5.5-1.1 12.9z"/>
  </g>
 
</svg>
```

### Update

Связанные вопросы:
[Преобразование шрифта HTML в SVG кривые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1152917/28748)
[Преобразование текста в path](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/806426/28748)
[Как нарисовать букву S?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1110672/28748)

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял через код элемента, входящее сообщение это загрузочный экран. При  загрузке, сайт просто подключает гифку, после чего меняет opacity загрузочного экрана с transition, либо через display: none

Comment: Там не гифка...